# How to add a delay for a 2 or 3 seconds

Tags: c#, delay

How can I add a delay to a program in C#?

Comment: There are several ways of doing this, but *why* do you need to add a delay? If we knew then we'd be able to suggest the most appropriate way to do it.

Comment: This question is hopelessly under-documented to ever recommend Thread.Sleep().

Comment: Just for clarification, I voted to close this question because you haven't provided enough detail for anyone to give a good, quality answer. I'm perfectly willing to reopen it as a valid question if you add some more detail on exactly what you're trying to do. Voting to close early is a way of preventing a flood of "noise" answers to poor quality questions. Once you've added more detail, leave me a comment and/or flag a mod to get it reopened.

Comment: Bad decision to close this question. It IS a question, and it is ok for it to be generic in nature. I understood it perfectly.

Comment: Yet another question I was searching for, answered by a question that was closed for no reason.

Comment: [This is why this question needs to be re-opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449956/how-to-add-a-delay-for-a-2-or-3-seconds#comment51463756_5449962). It's now out of date but no one can add an up to date answer as it's closed.

Comment: Let's reopen...

Answer (score 229):

You could use `Thread.Sleep()` function, e.g.

```
int milliseconds = 2000;
Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
```

that **completely stops** the execution of the current thread for 2 seconds.

Probably the most appropriate scenario for `Thread.Sleep` is when you want to delay the operations in another thread, different from the main  e.g. :

```
 MAIN THREAD        --------------------------------------------------------->
 (UI, CONSOLE ETC.)      |                                      |
                         |                                      |
 OTHER THREAD            ----- ADD A DELAY (Thread.Sleep) ------>
```

For other scenarios (e.g. starting operations after some time etc.) check [Cody's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5449967/316644).

Comment: Avoid using Thead.Sleep cause It will completely block the current Thread from doing ANYTHING till the duration ends.

Comment: @Mohammed: yes, of course it will completely block the tread. But sometimes it can be useful... it really depends on what the OP needs...

Comment: Since I can't post a new answer, I'd like to comment -- If you don't want it to block the program, you can use `await Task.Delay(milliseconds)`. This worked for me :)

Comment: In my case I couldn't use await because I was called from a part of the programm that is written by someone else. It is not awaitable but if I "hang" I can work for 10 seconds before my stuff is shut down. Sleeping 2 secs works like a charm ;) So in some cases this is the way.

Comment: @MohammedElSayed : The answer is depends.  It all depends on the intention of the use.  As for my case, I need to sleep the thread for 0.6 seconds precisely in order to avoid an index constrain when inserting into the database.

Answer (score 94):

**Use a timer with an interval set to 2–3 seconds.**

You have three different options to choose from, depending on which type of application you're writing:

1. [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)
2. [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)
3. [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

Don't use [`Thread.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) if your application need to process any inputs on that thread at the same time (WinForms, WPF), as `Sleep` will completely lock up the thread and prevent it from processing other messages. Assuming a single-threaded application (as most are), your entire application will stop responding, rather than just delaying an operation as you probably intended. Note that it may be fine to use Sleep in pure console application as there are no "events" to handle or on separate thread (also `Task.Delay` is better option).

In addition to timers and `Sleep` you can use [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.8) which is asynchronous version of `Sleep` that does not block thread from processing events (if used properly - don't turn it into infinite sleep with [`.Wait()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock)).

```
 public async void ClickHandler(...)
 {
      // whatever you need to do before delay goes here         

      await Task.Delay(2000);

      // whatever you need to do after delay.
 }
```

The same `await Task.Delay(2000)` can be used in a `Main` method of a console application if you use C# 7.1 ([Async main on MSDN blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/)).

Note: delaying operation with `Sleep` has benefit of avoiding race conditions that comes from potentially starting multiple operations with timers/`Delay`. Unfortunately freezing UI-based application is not acceptable so you need to think about what will happen if you start multiple delays (i.e. if it is triggered by a button click) - consider disabling such button, or canceling the timer/task or making sure delayed operation can be done multiple times safely.

Comment: If it is a console application, the `Thread.Sleep` warning may not be as important.

Comment: There is a 4th timer: [System.Web.UI.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx), an ASP.NET component that performs asynchronous or synchronous web page postbacks at a regular interval.

Comment: Should be top answer. If this had an example for using one of the timers, it would get more votes...

Comment: Cody Gray, can you add `await Task.Delay()` version and inline comment that console app actually likely *want* to use `Sleep` (non-async `Main`) or `Delay` (async `Main`)

Comment: To be honest, this is no longer my expertise, @Alexei. I haven't touched C# or .NET in...5 years? I haven't kept up with the latest developments. I don't know anything about `async`. Please feel free to edit the answer if you are confident in your ability to improve it.

Answer (score 45):

For 2.3 seconds you should do:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2300);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(
    (int)System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3).TotalMilliseconds);
```

Or with `using` statements:

```
Thread.Sleep((int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).TotalMilliseconds);
```

I prefer this to `1000 * numSeconds` (or simply `3000`) because it makes it more obvious what is going on to someone who hasn't used `Thread.Sleep` before.  It better documents your intent.

Comment: +1 for TimeSpan over 1000*

Comment: With .NET 4 onwards you can use `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan)` directly, without having to cast to an int.