# Task.Delay() not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Task.Delay() not behaving as expected or rather I'm not understanding what it is supposed to do. I'm trying to get my head around `Task`s in C# and how to replace `Thread`s in my implementation.

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

- While true

  - print a line
  - wait for a second,
  - If condition is satisfied, exit loop, otherwise keep looping

I've got that implemented with Threads fine, but all cool kids say I should be using Task, and don't touch Thread.

So for the code I have this (Ignore `[Test]` - this just a convenient way to try out things)

```
    [Test]
    public void ChattyTask()
    {
        var chattyTask = new Task(ChattyWriter);
        chattyTask.Start();
        chattyTask.Wait();
    }

    public void ChattyWriter()
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            var message = String.Format("Chatty Writer number {0}", count);
            Trace.WriteLine(message);
            count++;
            Task.Delay(1000);

            if (count >= 20)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this, the test finishes in milliseconds, not in 20 seconds as I would expect. If I replace `Task.Delay()` with `Thread.Sleep()`, everything works as expected and I get the printout once a second. I have tried adding `async` and `await` into `ChattyWriter()`, but not only it did not add a 1 second delay, it only printed only one line instead of 20.

What am I doing wrong?

Probably It'll help to describe what I'm doing: my project works with external API (RESTful) and after I request some tasks to happen, I need to poll the API to check if the task has been completed. External tasks can be long running: 1-15 minutes. So I need some delay between checking for completion. And there could be many different concurrent processes executed with multiple external tasks. I understand, that if I use `Thread.Sleep()` when polling, other processes on the same `Thread` will be blocked for no good reason.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`Task.Delay` returns a `Task` object on which you have to wait. Otherwise the following code will be executed immediately. Therfore you have to declare your method as `async`. Then you can await `Task.Delay`

```
public async Task ChattyWriter()
{
    int count = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        var message = String.Format("Chatty Writer number {0}", count);
        Trace.WriteLine(message);
        count++;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
           ...
    }
}
```

You have to interrupt your calling thread somehow. The unit test would terminate and the background thread as well. But if you call this method from the UI, the UI will not get blocked.

By calling `Wait` on an asynchronous method you will end up with a deadlock. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock) for more information.

Comment: I did try this, and it gave me only first line printed out and completed right after that.

Comment: That's probably because your main thread (the test routine) can go on running and you don't see the rest, because the program terminates. Would you start the thread from a UI button, the UI would still be responsive.

Comment: You are absolutely correct on this one! I've placed `Thread.Sleep(20000)` in the test routine and got what was expecting.

Answer (score 31):

`Task.Delay(1000);` creates an async task that will complete after a second, but the execution of the current method will continue in parallel.

In order to wait for the task to complete first, you could replace

```
Task.Delay(1000);
```

with

```
Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
```

Comment: @trailmax But this creates a new task that does nothing for one second. A much better approach is to simply call Thread.Sleep(1000).

Comment: @trailmax while my post explains why `Task.Delay` wasn't working, please consider using the approach described in [slfan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18672852/390819), which is more efficient.

Comment: is there a principal difference between the approaches? I always through that `async await` is just a syntactic sugar for compiler?

Comment: @trailmax the difference is that `Task.Wait()` is synchronous. In your case it doesn't make much difference, since you're anyway calling `Wait()` on the containing task (`chattyTask`). So, consider changing that to be async as well.

Comment: @Alberto If I have more than one Task running on the same thread (that is possible according to MSDN), and call `Thread.Sleep()`, that would block other tasks. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Task.Delay has an advantage that it is cancellable when passing a CancellationToken.

Answer (score 2):

Task.Delay() actually creates a task, so you just need to wait for it.

Try this

```
        public static void ChattyWriter()
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            var message = String.Format("Chatty Writer number {0}", count);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            count++;
            var t = Task.Delay(1000);
            t.Wait();

            if (count >= 20)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The primary reason why Task.Delay returns a Task is, that you can call await on it. Your answer is the same as @w0lf's