# Invoke failed in a task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, invoke

I have this code :

```
var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // Code...
    Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Increment(1)));
    // Code...
});

task.Wait();
```

But the Invoke fail, without Exception or any kind of error.
It seems that the "wait" prevents the refresh of the form, probably because I'm still in the method.

how do I get around this?

Thanks

Comment: is this a WPF application?

Comment: As a side note, this usage of `Task.Factory.StartNew` violates the guideline [CA2008: Do not create tasks without passing a TaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got yourself a dead-lock.

When the Task is running (on a different thread) and you call `Invoke`, it wants to invoke it on the mainthread. But the mainthread is waiting for the Task to complete...  *(task.Wait() will block until it's ready)*

What if you use:

```
await task;
```

*The method using this code should be marked as async.* The compiler will cut the method into pieces, and while waiting, the messageloop/thread runs again. When the task is ready, the rest of the method will be executed. (below the await task;)

---

Look here for more info: [await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock)

Answer (score 3):

This is a deadlock. The UI thread is blocking on the `task.Wait()` line, waiting for the task to finish. The task is blocking on `Invoke` because it needs to tell the UI thread to update the progress bar.

You should **NOT** be waiting for a task to complete on the UI thread, and should remove `task.Wait()`. The UI will update as soon as the task finishes.

Any code you were going to put below `task.Wait()` should go inside the Invoke action:

```
var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // do task work

    Invoke(new Action(() => {
        progressBar.Increment(1);
        // other code that needs the task to be finished should go here
    }));
});

// don't call task.Wait() here
```