# Batch upload using HttpClient.PutAsync()

Tags: c#, azure-storage, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to use HttpClient.PutAsync() to upload several images to Windows Azure storage at the same time. The code snippet looks like:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> putThumbnail = httpclient.PutAsync(new Uri(ThumbnailSas), thumbcontent);

Task<HttpResponseMessage> putImage = httpclient.PutAsync(new Uri(ImageSas), imagecontent);

Task.WaitAll(new Task<HttpResponseMessage>[] {putThumbnail, putImage});
```

Strangely in this way the server does not return at all so Task.WaitAll will wait forever.

if I change the code using await, the server returns and I can get the result correctly.

```
HttpResponseMessage result = await httpclient.PutAsync(new Uri(ThumbnailSas), thumbcontent);
```

How can I batch upload images using HttpClient.PutAsync?

Comment: possible duplicate of [await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock) - I believe there is nothing in specific about PutAsync, but rather the fact you are synchronously waiting (`WaitAll`) for all results blocking completion of `PutAsync` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't block on `async` code, [as I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

In this case, you can use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> putThumbnail = ...;
Task<HttpResponseMessage> putImage = ...;
await Task.WhenAll(putThumbnail, putImage);
```

Also see Figure 5 in my [MSDN article on `async` best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) or the end of my [`async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: this is the exact answer. :) and thanks for sharing the great blog.