# JSON and Async/Await

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

I am trying to parse data from a json file but I am getting variable outputs(Sometimes right, othertimes nothing). I am pretty much sure it is related with the time needed to parse the file, but having trouble finding out where. Here it is-

```
public class HspitalVM
{
    List<Hspital> hspitalList=null;
    public List<KeyedList<string, Hspital>> GroupedHospitals
    {
        get
        {
            getJson();
            var groupedHospital =
                from hspital in hspitalList
                group hspital by hspital.Type into hspitalByType
                select new KeyedList<string, Hspital>(hspitalByType);

            return new List<KeyedList<string, Hspital>>(groupedHospital);
        }
    }


    public async void getJson()
    {
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        try
        {
            StorageFile textFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(m_HospFileName);

            using (IRandomAccessStream textStream = await textFile.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                using (DataReader textReader = new DataReader(textStream))
                {

                    uint textLength = (uint)textStream.Size;
                    await textReader.LoadAsync(textLength);
                    string jsonContents = textReader.ReadString(textLength);

                    hspitalList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Hspital>>(jsonContents) as List<Hspital>;


                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string err = "Exception: " + ex.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(err);
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: Your `async` function should return a `Task`. Change your get call to  `await getJson();`

Comment: You may find my [`async` properties](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) blog post helpful (in addition to my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) post).

Answer (score 1):

You are not `await`-ing result of `getJson()` call, so as expected most of the times you'll get no information because actual call to `GetFileAsync` is not completed yet.

Now since `getJson` method returns `void` you can't really await on it. Potential fix by using `Result` to turn asynchronous code into synchronous for `get`:

```
public List<KeyedList<string, Hspital>> GroupedHospitals
{
    get
    {
        hspitalList= getJson().Result;
        ...
    }
}
...
public async Task<IList<Hspital>> getJson()
{
   ....
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Hspital>>(jsonContents) as List<Hspital>;
}
```

Note: It is generally bad idea to make `get` methods to perform long operations, also calling async method in synchronous way via `Wait`/`Result` can cause deadlocks in your code -[await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock).

Comment: its already causing deadlocks,i.e. its freezing the UI. I know the dos and donts of asynchronous coding but having trouble implementing them.

Comment: @LamiaMehreen - note that "freezing UI" and [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) are two different concepts - if "freezing" eventually will stop (when long operation is complete), while "deadlock" will never resolve itself.