# How do I call a method that returns a Task<T> From an ASP.Net MVC4 Controller Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, task-parallel-library, instagram

**TL;DR:** I would like to know how I can get the return value from a method that returns `Task<T>` when invoked from an **ASP.Net MVC4** Controller's `ActionResult` method. Code snippets below.

**Question Details:**
I'm using the [Instasharp Library](https://github.com/burkeholland/instasharp) on **github**.

Here's the `Search` method that returns `Task<UserResponse>`. This is defined in the Instasharp Library.

```
/// <summary>
/// Search for a user by name.
/// <para>
/// <c>Requires Authentication: False</c>
/// </para>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="searchTem">A query string.</param>
/// <param name="count">Number of users to return.</param>
/// <returns>UsersResponse</returns>
public Task<UsersResponse> Search(string searchTerm, int? count = null) {
    var request = base.Request("search");

    request.AddParameter("q", searchTerm);
    request.AddParameter("count", count);

    return base.Client.ExecuteAsync<UsersResponse>(request);
}
```

Here's a Unit Test in the same library project's source code, that works. If I put a breakpoint at the `Assert` line and inspect the `result`, it contains an instance of `List<UserResponse>` with data from the Instagram API.

```
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Users.Search")]
    public async Task Search()
    {
        var result = await users.Search("shiva");
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Data.Count > 0);
    }
```

In my ASP.Net MVC4 Application's `HomeController`, in the `Index` method that will query the instagram API and return a strong type `List<Instasharp.Models.User>` (which is contained in the `Data` property of the `UserResponse` object) to the corresponding View, the code is as follows. ( Note: This is per the documentation on the Github page and is supposed to work.).

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var userList = new List<InstaSharp.Models.User>();
            var mediaList = new List<InstaSharp.Models.Media>();
            var followingList = new List<InstaSharp.Models.User>();
            try
            {
                 var config = new InstaSharp.InstagramConfig(
                     clientId:"MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM",
                     clientSecret:"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

                 InstaSharp.Endpoints.Users users = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Users(config);
                  var result = users.Search("shiva");
                  userList = result.Result.Data;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace.ToString();
            }

            return View(userList);
        }
    }
```

**The Problem:**
 My code is hanging (i.e. `localhost:portnumber` is just waiting.). There are no issues authenticating with Instagram API. The line

`var result = users.Search("shiva");`

is showing that result is a `Task`. I am not sure how to invoke it and get the `Data` in the return value from the `users.Search("shiva")` method.

**What I have Tried:**
I've tried adding the `await` in front of the `users.Search("shiva")` call. Then the compiler is asking me to make the `ActionResult Index()` also `async` and wrap a `Task<..>` around it. When I did that also, the code is hanging. 
I also tried looking on MSDN [at this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4), but that didn't help either.
I've spent quite a few hours on this, and am hoping someone on SO can help me.

[Note: This is not production code. I am simply trying to get the Instasharp library working in an ASP.Net MVC4 Controller and display data in a View. So please don't get fixated on coding practices etc. Also, I've faked out the `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` for the question. I don't think you would need it to answer this question.]

Comment: Side note: there are plenty of similar questions with explanation of "deadlock when using Wait/Result in ASP.Net"...

Comment: Thanks @AlexeiLevenkov I just am not sure how to make the invocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To properly make calls to `async` methods in MVC4+  you should make your actions asynchronous by returning `Task<ActionResult>` and using `await` to wait for completion of the `async` methods.

Covered in details in following MSDN article [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) (as well many others). Sample from article below:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GizmosAsync()
{
    var gizmoService = new GizmoService();
    var result = await gizmoService.GetGizmosAsync();
    return View("Gizmos", result);
}
```

Note that using `Wait` or `Result` in ASP.Net will cause deadlock (as you observe). There are many questions/articles discussing it -i.e. [await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock)