# Get result from async method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have this method in my service:

```
public virtual async Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
{
    this.ThrowIfDisposed();
    if (userId == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("userId");
    }
    return await this.repository.FindByIdAsync(userId);
}
```

and then in a view I have this code:

```
using (var service = new UserService(new CompanyService(), User.Identity.GetUserId()))
{
    var user = service.FindByIdAsync(id);
}
```

but the user is the **Task** and not the **User**. I tried adding **await** to the service call, but I can't use **await** unless the current method is **async**.
How can I access the **User** class?

Comment: Make the current method async and add await.

Comment: Can you show the code of the `service.FindByIdAsync(id)`?

Comment: 'async' methods are like zombies: they propagate. Async methods callers must be async.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best solution is to make the calling method `async` and then use `await`, as Bas Brekelmans pointed out.

When you make a method `async`, you should change the return type (if it is `void`, change it to `Task`; otherwise, change it from `T` to `Task<T>`) and add an `Async` suffix to the method name. If the return type *cannot* be `Task` because it's an event handler, then you can use `async void` instead.

If the calling method is a constructor, you can use [one of these techniques](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) from my blog. It the calling method is a property getter, you can use [one of these techniques](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) from my blog.

Comment: Say mate... Are you the core developer of the .net framework? You are deeply involved in concurrent development in c#

Comment: @IamStalker: Haha, no. I don't work for Microsoft. I just have a lot of experience in concurrent apps so I understand where they're coming from especially with `async`. There is a fellow named Stephen *Toub* who does work for Microsoft and has been deeply involved with TPL, Dataflow, and `async`.

Comment: Stephen, The problem I have is that my View is virtual so it calls my service but it is not a function so I can't prepend async :( is there some other work around?

Comment: The code calling `FindByIdAsync` *must* be in a method... Why can't you make that method `async`?

Answer (score 12):

- Using `this` in `async` methods without special thread-locked object is **dangerous**
- If you cannot use `await`, use a code like following.

  ```
  Task<User> task = TaskFindByIdAsync();

  task.Wait(); //Blocks thread and waits until task is completed

  User resultUser = task.Result;
  ```

Comment: This is a really bad practice. It may be a hidden deadlock. [see this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: @Olivier Looks like it does not depend so. Only unclear code in task [may cause a deadlock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock)

Comment: A good habit is to never rely on **how** methods are implemented when calling them. If the Wait() is on the context thread, and method Waited (not A-waited) uses an 'await', then you will deadlock (because it waits for the main thread to be available).

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by 'Using this in async methods without special thread-locked object is dangerous'. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @jeroenh Because `async` methods are often ran **simultaneously** and they may encounter a concurrency conflict sharing `this`. For example, [singleton locks not on `this`, but on special `object` field](http://ilyatereschuk.blogspot.com/2013/12/c-simple-singleton-blank-for-everyday.html)

Comment: Using '`this` in a 'readonly' way (i.e., reading fields) is perfectly safe, even multithreaded way. I see no need for locks in the code of the OP.

Comment: this is completely outdated and can't be used now.

Comment: Thanks this helped me alot.