# How to get url parameter to my controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm making a function to reset the password of a user using ASP.NET Identity. However, the token is not being picked up in my controller. When I submit the form, it says

> "The Token field is required."

Why does it not pick up my token?
Following code is being used to generate the resetLink:

```
    var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(email).Result;

    if (user == null || !_userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user).Result)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Error while resetting your password!";
        return View("ResetPassword");
    }

    var token = _userManager.
          GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user).Result;

    var resetLink = Url.Action("SetPassword",
                    "Auth", new { token },
                     protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
```

This generates the link: `http://localhost:50015/adviseur/auth/setpassword?token=someverylongnumbers`

This link goes to the following view, viewmodel and controller:
AuthController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SetPassword()
{
    return View();
}
```

SetPassword.cshtml

```
@model SetPasswordModel

<h1>Set Your Password</h1>

<form asp-controller="Auth"
      asp-action="RequestNewPassword"
      method="post">

    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Token" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label asp-for="UserName"></label></td>
            <td><input asp-for="UserName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label asp-for="Password">
                    New Password
                </label>
            </td>
            <td><input asp-for="Password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword">
                    Confirm New Password
                </label>
            </td>
            <td><input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit"
                       value="Reset Password" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>

</form>
```

SetPasswordModel.cs:

```
#region Using

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

#endregion

namespace x.Areas.Adviseur.ViewModels
{
    public class SetPasswordModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Token { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The form makes the request to the following controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult RequestNewPassword(SetPasswordModel obj)
{
    User user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(obj.UserName).Result;
    IdentityResult result = _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, obj.Token, obj.Password).Result;

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Password reset successful!";
        return View("Login");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Error while resetting the password!";
        return View("SetPassword");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the token in your `obj` an empty string or null or is it actually the token?

Comment: @Marco It doesn't even reach the controller, it seems to be an issue in the view/viewmodel.

Comment: The SetPassword.cshtml must have a get action method, that must return this view. Add that to your question please, because that is what generates the view model.

Comment: @Marco added the controller that contains the view

Comment: Your generated link contains token query variable this means you can handle it from controller like : 
`public IActionResult SetPassword([FromQuery]string token) {...` Otherwise token  is always be null.

Comment: Does the error appear in your browser?

Comment: Please consider making your actions `async` and using `await` instead of using `.Result` everywhere you call asynchronous methods. See [Get result from async method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20884604/215552) and [How to justify using await instead of .Result() or .Wait() in .NET Core?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/398998/222246) on [softwareengineering.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the token is not being picked up in my controller

That is because you haven't send it. You are not collecting the token from the url to use it on the next step. Therefore, at the `RequestNewPassword` action method, the model binder cannot find a value in the `Token` form-field, and it cannot create a `SetPasswordModel` object without a value for the `Token` property because you have marked it as `Required`. Hence the complain -

> "The Token field is required."

At your `SetPassword` action method -

1. Add a string parameter named `token` to the method, so that the model binder can collect the token string from the url
2. Pass the token to the view through the `ViewBag` or the model.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SetPassword(string token)
{
    ViewBag.Token = token;
    return View();

    // OR,
    // var model = new SetPasswordModel { Token = token };
    // return View(model);
}
```

If you pass the token through the model, then no change is needed in the view. But if you pass it through the `ViewBag`, then set it to the `Token` form-field -

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Token" value="@ViewBag.Token" />
```

Now, when you submit the form, at `RequestNewPassword` action method, the model binder will be able to create a `SetPasswordModel` object for you without complaining.

Comment: I didn't even need the ViewBag.Token = token, but adding it in the constructor did work. Thanks!

Comment: @SomeName I updated the answer. Right now its working for you because the name of the method parameter and the form-field are same in lower case (`token`). But that might not always be case. So, you **should** always explicitly pass the token to the view.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Good to know. Thanks for the update!