# Wait on a task invoked in a delegate

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I have a controller method which looks something like this:

```
[HttpPut, Route("cqs/command")]
public HttpResponseMessage Command([ValueProvider(typeof(HeaderValueProviderFactory))] string typeName)
{
    object reply = null;
    var code = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    try
    {
        var cmdObject = DeserializeRequest(typeName);
        var method = _commandMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        method.Invoke(this, new object[] { request });
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        reply = exception;
    }

    var responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage(code);
    if (reply != null)
    {
        responseMsg.Headers.Add("X-TypeName", reply.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);
        var replyJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reply);
        responseMsg.Content = new StringContent(replyJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    }
    return responseMsg;
}
```

Which invokes the following method:

```
private void ExecuteCommand<T>(T command) where T : Command
{
    var task = _commandBus.ExecuteAsync(command);
    task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
}
```

The reason to that is that the `_commandBus` only have a generic method which I need to invoke.

The problem is however that the `ExecuteCommand` seems to deadlock at some times. I can't figure out why. The `ICommandBus.ExecuteAsync` method will invoke other tasks using async/await, so it might be some kind of dead lock since WebApi uses a synchronization context? ([await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock))

So if I understand it all correctly, there might be two solutions:

1. use async/await all the way. But how do I do that when invoking a method using `MethodInfo`?
2. Change so that my invocation works with the synchronization context

I'm lost when it comes to both solutions. Can anyone help?

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to come from invoking the delegate though, it comes from the fact that you're doing a blocking wait on the task, when you should be asynchronously waiting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `ExecuteCommand<T>` so that it looks like this (I'm assuming your actual code will *do* something on a timeout):

```
private async Task ExecuteCommandAsync<T>(T command) where T : Command
{
  var timeout = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
  var task = _commandBus.ExecuteAsync(command);
  await Task.WhenAny(task, timeout);
}
```

And make whatever calls it `async Task` as well. Then, when you invoke the method, you can do this:

```
var task = method.Invoke(this, new object[] { request }) as Task;
await task;
```

Comment: That works for the Command execution. But the Query variant returns a generic task. What is the best way to handle that?

Comment: `Task<T>` inherits from `Task`, so if you just want to `await` it you don't need to do anything else. If you need to return a result somehow, I'd recommend `dynamic`.