# Wait() causes UI thread to hang - when should Wait() be used?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, signalr, async-await

I have the following code that connects to a SignalR Hub

```
    private static async Task StartListening()
    {
        try
        {


            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/");                
            IHubProxy hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("Broadcaster");
            hubProxy.On<EventData>("notifyCardAccessEvent", eventData =>
            {
                Log.Info(string.Format("Incoming data: {0} {1}", eventData.Id, eventData.DateTime));
            });
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;
            await hubConnection.Start();
            Log.Info("Connected");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex);
        }
    }
```

In my `Form_Load` method, I have this

```
StartListening();
```

However, Resharper prompts me to "consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call"

So I did this:

```
Log.Info("Connecting to SignalR hub...");
StartListening().Wait();
Log.Info("Connected!");
```

However, this causes my UI thread to hang and `Connected!` is never printed to the log file.

So my question is, when should I use `Wait()`? What are the instances and scenarios that I should use Wait(), and when should I not use `Wait()`?

Comment: So, it said "consider applying await" and then you did something different - why have you decided not to follow the advice and actually use `await`?

Comment: Ahhhh yes! Overlooked that on my part. I thought they were the same. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`await` is not `Wait`. It is unclear what the code is that is calling `StartListening()`, but one option is to `await` it, as suggested:

```
await StartListening();
```

However, in some other cases it may be better to do nothing at all:

```
StartListening(); // drop the Task on the floor
```

or perhaps use `ContinueWith` for a manual continuation. Since the `StartListening` method catches any exceptions, there isn't anything wrong with just ignoring the returned `Task` - so what you had already. I would suggest calling it `StartListeningAsync`, though.

The reason for the deadlock is that if you use `Wait`, your UI thread blocks waiting on an asynchronous method to complete, but that asynchronous method is capturing the sync-context, which means in order to process each continuation it tries to get onto the UI thread - which is blocked... *on it*.

Comment: @the8thbit far from; `Wait` is if I ask you to do something, and then I stand right behind you and do nothing else until you've finished it. `await` is if I ask you to do something, and then come and tap me on the shoulder when you've finished and when I'm not in the middle of something. Kind of. Analogies suck ;p The "sync context" in this is *sort of* "how to get my attention" - but that is stretching things a bit ;p But to illustrate: one option is to tell it *not to* capture the sync-context - in *that* case, when you've finished, **you** would go and do whatever it is I wanted done next

Comment: @the8thbit or, depending on the exact scenario, you'd leave a "go do this next" in the in-tray of the worker pool

Answer (score 4):

@MarcGravell has the correct answer; I'm just going to answer this other question:

> So my question is, when should I use Wait()? What are the instances and scenarios that I should use Wait(), and when should I not use Wait()?

The confusion is coming from the fact that the `Task` type is used for two almost completely different things.

`Task` was originally introduced in .NET 4.0 as part of the Task Parallel Library. Normally, you would use Parallel LINQ or the `Parallel` class for parallel processing (which used the `Task` type underneath). However, [in advanced scenarios, you could use the `Task` type directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963551.aspx). `Task.Wait` was used to wait for those independent tasks to complete.

When `async`/`await` were introduced in .NET 4.5, the existing `Task` type was *almost* good enough to be used as an abstract "future". So instead of inventing some new "future" type, they just slightly extended `Task` to work as a future.

This brings us to today, where `Task` can be used as either:

- An item of work in a parallel computation.
- An asynchronous future.

(There's a tiny bit of crossover: you can treat parallel work as asynchronous, and in rare situations like Console `Main` methods you do need to block on asynchronous tasks; but ignore those for the moment.)

This means that the API for `Task` is split along those lines. Members such as `Start`, `Wait`, `Result`, and `ContinueWith` belong pretty firmly on the parallel side. In the asynchronous world, `await` is more appropriate.

I have a small table at the bottom of my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that has some new (asynchronous) equivalents for the old (parallel) ways of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to misunderstand the message from Resharper. Instead of applying the `await` operator, you called the `Task.Wait()` Method. They may seem similar, but they're working completely different.

This nice answer will provide more information about the differences: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13140963/3465395