# Is it possible to use Task<bool> in if conditions?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

In Windows Phone 8 I have method `public async Task<bool> authentication()`. The return type of the function is `bool` but when I tried to use its returned value in a `if` condition error says can not convert `Task<bool>` to `bool`.

```
public async Task<bool> authentication()
{
    var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("user", _username),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("password", _password)
    };

    var serverData = serverConnection.connect("login.php", pairs);

    RootObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(await serverData);

    if (json.logined != "false")
    {
        _firsname = json.data.firsname;
        _lastname = json.data.lastname;
        _id = json.data.id;
        _phone = json.data.phone;
        _ProfilePic = json.data.profilePic;
        _thumbnail = json.data.thumbnail;
        _email = json.data.email;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: No you can't use it directly since `Task<bool>` is not a `bool`. You should post the code you're actually having a problem with, but you can probably do `bool b = await authentication(); if(b) { ... }`

Comment: Your "async" authentication method doesn't await anything, so it's nto actually asynchronous

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The return type of your function is `Task<bool>`, not `bool` itself. To get the result, you should use `await` keyword:

```cs
bool result = await authentication();
```

You can read *"What Happens in an Async Method"* section of this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) to get more understanding on `async / await` language feature.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` the task:

```
bool result = await authentication();
```

Or, you can use your favourite alternate method of waiting on a `Task`.

Comment: Using async/await choosing one of the "alternate methods" (`Task.Wait()` or `Task.Result`) can often lead to [deadlock situations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock).