# debugging conditional statements using task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout) answers how we can asynchronously wait for a task to finish with a timeout.

I have written a similar async method as shown below, which checks if the current value is greater that some defined threshold value.

```
public async Task<bool> FindThreshold(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{            
    await Task.Run(()=> { 
        if (this.currentValue >= this.ThresholdValue) {
            this.ThresholdFound = true; 
        } else { 
            this.ThresholdFound = false; 
        } 
    });
    if (ThresholdFound)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Based on the similar solution [given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout) I am calling the function as shown below,

```
var found = await FindThresholdAsyncAsync(cts);
if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(
    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(timeout)*1000),
    cts.Token) == found)
{
    await found;
}
```

The error message says that Operator "==" cannot be applied to operands of the type 'Task' and 'bool'. I do understand that Task.Delay returns a task but I couldn't figure out why it is working in case of the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout). Clearly, I am missing something so any insights would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mustn't await the result of `FindThreshold`. `Task.WhenAny` takes a list of task and returns the first one to end. You must compare that to the task returned by `FindThreshold` to know whether it timed out. **Then** you can retrieve the result.

```
var task = FindThreshold(cts);
if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(
    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(timeout)*1000),
    cts.Token)) == task)
{
    var found = task.Result; // No need to await because we know the task is completed
}
else
{
    // Timeout
}
```

Comment: since FindThreshold has a return type of Task<bool> it still complains at the usage of '==' saying cannot convert from 'bool' to System.Threading.Task.Task. Also, I was using the await keyword since according to this solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272911/is-it-possible-to-use-taskbool-in-if-conditions) I have to await the FindThreshold method since I am returning Task<bool> and not bool.

Comment: Well that's the point. You don't await because you need a Task for the comparison and not a bool. Only after the check, you await (or call `.Result`) to get the bool. Try the code in my answer, you won't have the error

Comment: @kosol Actually it was missing a parenthesis. Fixed.

Comment: I feel so stupid that even i missed that in my code. It is very clear to me now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: i forgot to mention that according to the article here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) one should avoid using task.result since it blocks the async code. So would using task.result a good idea in my case ?

Comment: @kosol In your case we already know that the task is completed, so `.Result` won't block. In fact, the `await` keyword has a special optimization for this case where it checks whether the task is already completed and just calls `.Result` (actually, it calls  `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` but that's pretty much the same thing). So by using `.Result` instead of `await`, we have the same behavior but we're avoiding the extra bit of plumbing

Comment: @KooKiz: I still prefer `await` over `Result` even if the task is already completed for two reasons: 1) `Result` wraps exceptions in an `AggregateException`, which complicates error handling; and 2) `await` is more resilient to future code changes (i.e., the genius down the hall changes the method so that the task is no longer guaranteed to be complete at that point).