# cannot return value from async method in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I'm trying to return value from `async` html helper but it is giving following string instead of desired values.

> "System.Threading.Tasks.Task+WhenAllPromise`1[System.Decimal]"

Method:

```
public async static Task<decimal> CalculateCurrency(this HtmlHelper helper, decimal amount, string from, string country)
    {
        if (await getValue(country))
        {
            string fromCurrency = string.IsNullOrEmpty(from) ? "USD" : from;
            string toCurrency = country;
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string url = string.Format("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s={0}{1}=X", fromCurrency.ToUpperInvariant(), toCurrency.ToUpperInvariant());
            Stream response = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(url);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response);
            string yahooResponse = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
            response.Close();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yahooResponse))
            {
                string[] values = Regex.Split(yahooResponse, ",");
                if (values.Length > 0)
                {
                    decimal rate = System.Convert.ToDecimal(values[1]);
                    string res = string.Format("{0:0.00}", rate * amount);
                    return decimal.Parse(res);
                 }
            }
            return decimal.Zero;
        }
        return decimal.Zero;
    }
```

Call HTML Helper:

```
@Html.CalculateCurrency(22, "USD", "EUR")
```

Comment: Its not a good idea to call asynchronous code from a view.

Comment: @DavidG how i can solve this issue? i want that method to run asynchronous

Comment: Do the asynchronous work inside the method but return synchronously.

Comment: @DavidG i want to improve application performance thats why i used async method, is there any other way to do this? or how i can do this with this method?

Comment: @Usama Async code isn't intended to improve performance, it's intended to improve *responsiveness*. For what you're doing here, the best approach would probably be to have an async controller method, which you call asynchronously from your front end via AJAX.

Comment: @DanielMann can u please guide me with code how i can do this?

Comment: Yes, @DanielMann beat me to the answer there! :)

Comment: @Usama I'm sorry, but I'm not going to write your code for you. I've given you a nudge in the right direction -- start researching! If you hit any problems, feel free to post another question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views don't support asynchronous methods. So as result you get result of default `.ToString()` function for type of result which indeed returns just type name.

Options:

- move code to controller and call in from asynchronous top level (non-child) action with `await`. Pass data to view via model or `ViewBag`
- convert to real synchronous code if you must call it from the view or child action
- if not possible try `.Result`, but watch out for deadlocks. See [await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock) for details/links.

Note: moving `async` code to child action will not help.