# HttpClient - how to figure out if server is down faster?

Tags: c#, .net, http, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using .NET `HttpClient` to send requests to my server. I have set `HttpClient.Timeout` property to 10 seconds so i'm getting a `A task was cancelled` exception whenever the server fails to process my request in less than 10 seconds. Good until here.

However, if the server is shut down it takes for the `HttpClient` around ~20 seconds to return a proper exception such as the one in the picture. [image]

I would like to see this exception faster than 10 seconds to be able to distinguish between Server Down and Operation took too long scenarios. I can't find anything about this in msdn documentation. Is there any timeout that can be set on the `HttpClient`?

Here's how i'm constructing the `HttpClient`

```
 var webRequestHandler = new WebRequestHandler
        {
            UseProxy = false,
            Proxy = null,
            AllowPipelining = false,
            ContinueTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero,
            UseCookies = false,
            AllowAutoRedirect = false,
        };
 var httpClient = new HttpClient(webRequestHandler);
 httpClient.Timeout = timeout;

  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");
  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", userAgent);
  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
```

Comment: Just a little analogy that i want you to think about: If you're on the phone with someone and ask a question. Is there a reliable (fast/immediate) way for you to determine whether the person you're talking to has fallen asleep or is just thinking real hard?

Comment: Logically what you are asking does not make sense, you can't know if you have not had a response because the server is down or because it has taken too long to process your request, you just haven't had a response.

Comment: I think logically it does make sense since there is a difference between having an HTTP response and a TCP connection.

Comment: Well, you may not have a reliable way to check if the person you are talking to has fallen or thinking, but if you have a rule for "hang up if I get no answer in 10 seconds", it should not take you 20 seconds to take action.

Comment: Take a look at ServicePointManager, there are a few properties which might help you. Another option would be to use an HttpWebRequest, which has a timeout for the response to start and one for the data to arrive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't handle this with timeouts, as mentioned in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A Domain Name System (DNS) query may take up to 15 seconds to return or time out. If your request contains a host name that requires resolution and you set Timeout to a value less than 15 seconds, it may take 15 seconds or more before a WebException is thrown to indicate a timeout on your request.

However, another approach would be wrapping your request in another task and handle timeout from there:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => { 
                var req = new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://www.google.com");
                if (!req.Wait(10000))//wait for 10 seconds
                    throw new TaskCanceledException(req);
            });
task.Wait();
```

Answer (score 14):

This answer just extends @brz's example.

You can use this approach that does not block the thread ( `Task.Wait` [blocks the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock))

```
var timeout = Task.Delay(10000); // 10 seconds timeout
var request = httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");

await Task.WhenAny(timeout, request); // wait for either timeout or the request

if (timeout.IsCompleted) // if the timeout ended first, then handle it
{
    // handle timeout
}

// otherwise continue processing the request result
var response = await request;
```