# Confused on how to structure async/await code that calls SmtpClient.SendMailAsync()

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I read the documentation for `async-await` feature, but still highly confused on how to structure `async-await` code that calls `SmtpClient.SendMailAsync()` method.
How should I rewrite the code to properly use `async-await` ?

Currently, my code looks like this:
Periodically `PrivateSignal` is being called by the system to send out email notifications.

```
public override void PrivateSignal(IEventInformation ev) 
{
    TagEvent tag = (TagEvent)ev;
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
           await smptClient.SendMailAsync(CaptureRC.SmptFromEmailAddr,
                                    ToEmails,
                                    CaptureRC.EmailSubject,
                                    "seen moving" + tag.ToString());
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
           //TODO handle the error
           //TODO log the erros, along with
        }
    }).Wait();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be making `PrivateSignal` `async` as well which includes marking it with `async` and returning a `Task`:

```
public override async Task PrivateSignalAsync(IEventInformation ev) 
{
    TagEvent tag = (TagEvent)ev;
    try
    {
       await smptClient.SendMailAsync(CaptureRC.SmptFromEmailAddr, ToEmails, CaptureRC.EmailSubject, "seen moving" + tag.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It seems, though, that you can't do that since `PrivateSignal` is overriding an already synchronous method. If you can change the base method to return a `Task` then you should, but if you can't then simply don't use `async` at all inside that method because blocking on `async` can lead to deadlocks and other unwanted results:

```
public override void PrivateSignal(IEventInformation ev) 
{
    TagEvent tag = (TagEvent)ev;
    try
    {
       smptClient.SendMail(CaptureRC.SmptFromEmailAddr, ToEmails, CaptureRC.EmailSubject, "seen moving" + tag.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: smptClient.SendMail() shouldn't throw an AggregateException.  AggregateException is something that TPL (Task, Task<T>, etc) methods throw.

Comment: Lets assume that I can change change the code to be asynchronous, same way as you have it. 1. How do I call this method from other function ? `await PrivateSignal(tag)` or `Task.Run(() => PrivateSignal(tag)).Await()` ? 2. Should the calling method be `async` as well ?

Comment: @newprint `await PrivateSignalAsync(tag)`. `Task.Run` should only be used to offload compute-bound work to a `ThreadPool` thread.

Comment: Another small question, you mentioned "blocking on `async` can lead to deadlocks and other unwanted results" . However `.Wait()` is blocking a thread on which `PrivateSignal` is running on, why it can cause deadlocks ?

Comment: @newprint [await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13140963/885318)

Answer (score 1):

async/await is the new hotness to replace things like `Task.Run` and `Task.Wait`. Try this:

```
public async override Task PrivateSignal(IEventInformation ev) 
{
    TagEvent tag = (TagEvent)ev;

    try
    {
        await smptClient.SendMailAsync(CaptureRC.SmptFromEmailAddr,
            ToEmails, CaptureRC.EmailSubject, "seen moving" + tag.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //TODO handle the error
        //TODO log the erros, along with
    }
}
```

The `await` causes the running thread to suspend until the Task completes (or is cancelled or experiences an error). The rest of the method is registered as a continuation automatically. async/await is therefore syntactic sugar for task-based asynchronous programming.

Also, it's important to avoid `async void` methods since the `void` support is reserved for event handlers. Instead of `void`, return `Task` for methods with no return value.

Finally, since this method is an `override`, you'd need to change the base method's return type to `Task` as well.