# Task that has asynchronous IO operation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await, task

(I am still in early stage of learning `async-await` and Task Parallel Library.)
I was asked to add some functionality to our existing project: send out email notification when system gets important data.

```
// part of API; called by other parts of the program
public override void PrivateSignal(IEventInformation ev) 
{
   // ... some light CPU processing of data

   // will do some IO bound (non-CPU bound) processing
   // in my case, send out email notification 
   // using `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`class
  smptClient.SendMail(CaptureRC.SmptFromEmailAddr, 
                                 ToEmails, CaptureRC.EmailSubject,   
                             "seen moving" + tag.ToString());
}
```

According to answers to my [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442967/confused-on-how-to-structure-async-await-code-that-calls-smtpclient-sendmailasyn) and [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) by Stephen Cleary, following construct is not a good choice to make my code "asynchronous":

```
public override void PrivateSignal(IEventInformation ev) {
    Task.Run(async ()=>{await smptClient.SendMailAsync(....);}).Wait();
}
```

Assume for the moment that `PrivateSignal()` was called 50 times in a row, and I would make IO operation synchronous:

```
public override void PrivateSignal(IEventInformation ev) {
        Task.Run(()=>{ smptClient.SendMail(....);}).WaitAll();
    }
```

This will create 50 threads in the pool, and each one of them will be blocked by synchronous call, in addition, `.WaitAll()`will block running thread (I can get rid of `.WaitAll()` since return from SendMail() is void). Overall, 51 threads stuck, doing nothing.

What could be possible be done to improve IO operation without wasting so much time and resources ?

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Run(async ()=>{await smptClient.SendMailAsync(....);}).Wait()` rather than `smptClient.SendMailAsync(....).Wait()`, or simply `smptClient.Send()`? They all block the calling thread. Also, does `PrivateSignal` really need to wait for the email to be fully sent, or can it just initiate sending and return to the caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What could be possible be done to improve IO operation without wasting so much time and resources?

The *best* answer is to make `PrivateSignal` asynchronous, just like the [accepted answer to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28443045/263693) suggested. Yes, this does mean that the base class has to change, and all the methods that call `PrivateSignal` have to change. They *have* to change in order to enable asynchrony.

If you don't want to change `PrivateSignal`, then `PrivateSignal` is forced to be synchronous. And that forces you to use `SendMail`, which blocks the thread. Because that's what synchronous *means*.

In order to be asynchronous, you *must* change `PrivateSignal` so that it can be asynchronous.

(Side note in interest of full disclosure: it is *possible* to declare `PrivateSignal` as an `async void` method. However, this raises a **whole host** of problems. For details, see the "avoid async void" section of [my MSDN article on async best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) or [do a search on that phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=avoid%20async%20void).)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an async SMTP client, like [`SmtpClient.SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Sends the specified e-mail message to an SMTP server for delivery. This method does not block the calling thread