# Catching async errors in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, loops, error-handling, async-await

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.Loop();
    }

    public async void Loop()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                var result = await SomeTask();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error" + i);
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> SomeTask()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        throw new Exception();
        return "Result";
    }
}
```

Output

```
0
Error0
1
```

I would expect the output to be more like this:

```
0
Error0
1
Error2
2
Error2
3
Error4
4
```

Why does it stop after 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not waiting for the `async` operation to complete and so the application ends before it the operation has a chance to complete.

You shouldn't be using `async void` outside of event handlers. `async void` doesn't return an awaitable and so the calling method simply moves on (and exits the app). You should return a `Task` and `await` it (or in the case of `Main` use `Task.Wait`):

```
public static void Main()
{
    var p = new Program();
    p.LoopAsync().Wait();
}

public async Task LoopAsync()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            var result = await SomeTask();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
Error0
1
Error1
2
Error2
3
Error3
4
Error4
```

Comment: So with `await` in the `Main` method, the program will exit, because although `Main` is paused, `Main` still returns to its caller (which I assume is the Common Language Runtime.) Result: the `LoopAsync` cannot complete because the CLR has stopped hosting it (or something like that.) Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock

Comment: @ShaunLuttin You can only use `await` in an `async` method, which `Main` can't be. That's why you need to use `Wait` instead. When you don't wait, you run `LoopAsync` synchronously until it reaches the first `await`, then it returns to the caller, which is `Main` which ends and exits the app.