# Hanging with WaitForConnectionAsync() on pipe

Tags: c#, asynchronous, pipe, named-pipes

I'm communicating with another process via named pipes. The pipe server is implemented in C# and the client is written in C. The server is a WPF application.

I need to create a `NamedPipeServerStream` and wait (synchronously) up to 1 second for the client to connect. And then I need to know whether the client connected.

As `NamedPipeServerStream`'s only way to cancel/timeout a wait for the client to connect is via its asynchronous `WaitForConnectionAsync` method - which takes a `CancellationToken` - I've implemented what I believe is a synchronous wait like so:

```
public bool WaitOneSecondForClientConnect()
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        result = WaitForConnectionAsyncSyncWrapper().Result;
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        log.Write("Error waiting for pipe client connect: " + e.InnerException.Message);
    }
    return result;
}

private async Task<bool> WaitForConnectionAsyncSyncWrapper()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(1000);
    await pipe.WaitForConnectionAsync(cts.Token);
    return pipe.IsConnected;
}
```

The pipe is defined like so: `NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 1, 1);`
The `WaitOneSecondForClientConnect()` function runs on the UI thread.

What should make it synchronous is accessing the async `WaitForConnectionAsyncSyncWrapper()` function's `Result` property on the `Task<bool>` it returns. In order to access the Result, the async function must have fully returned, and it can't execute the `return pipe.IsConnected` line until the function is resumed after `await pipe.WaitForConnectionAsync(cts.Token);` has completed. At least that's my understanding.

So the problem: although the client program says it's opened my server's pipe (which has already been created of course before the code above executes), `WaitOneSecondForClientConnect()` never returns. If I break into the server, it's on this line: `result = WaitForConnectionAsyncSyncWrapper().Result;`.

So I guess it's waiting for the Task's Result to be available, which should be the value of `pipe.IsConnected` if the client connected within 1 second, or it should throw an `AggregateException` when I access it if the `await` has completed because the token has been cancelled (after 1 second). But it's just hanging completely.

On the other hand, if I cancel the token before it starts e.g. by putting a `Thread.Sleep(2000);` right before calling `await pipe.WaitForConnectionAsync(cts.Token);`, then the connection is cancelled successfully (I think it doesn't even try to start because the token is already cancelled) - accessing the `Result` property throws an `AggregateException`, etc...

A few things to note.

- If I replace the content of `WaitOneSecondForClientConnect()` with a
  standard synchronous `pipe.WaitForConnection();`, it works every time -
  i.e. the client connects, and the function returns.
- In a test program I wrote to initially get this async/sync stuff working, connecting in this synchronous-asynchronous way works every time. It's a console program as opposed to my real program which is WPF. The relevant code of the test program is listed below.
- The code posted above has actually worked a couple of times, and failed maybe 30-40 times.
- If my client doesn't open my pipe, my "real" code still hangs, whereas my test code waits the specified time period and then prints "Connection failed." as expected (see below) - which is exactly the behaviour that should be happening in my real code.

The test code that works:

```
var pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("SemiUsefulPipe_" + pid.ToString() + "ctest", PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 1, 1);

// ... dll containing pipe client is injected in client process at this point.

try
{
    var result = ConnectAsync(pipe).Result;
}
catch (AggregateException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connection failed.");
}
```

...

```
private static async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(NamedPipeServerStream pipe)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(1000);
    await pipe.WaitForConnectionAsync(cts.Token);
    return pipe.IsConnected;
}
```

Comment: You are not using async/await correctly

Comment: Perhaps not - could you elaborate?

Comment: Your question is too long for me to take it all in and formulate an answer

Comment: duplicate [await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock) explains deadlock on calling `.Result` in WPF/WinForms/ASP.Net. You post nicely demonstrate good effort you put into finding the problem - kudos for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix async and non-async methods like this. What's happening is that your `WaitOneSecondForClientConnect` method is waiting for `WaitForConnectionAsyncSyncWrapper` method to complete. But that guy needs its calling thread to be free so it can rehydrate the original context. So you've just created a deadlock. For details, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx.

Instead, you need to go async all the way down.

```
public async Task<bool> WaitOneSecondForClientConnect()
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        result = await WaitForConnectionAsyncSyncWrapper();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Write("Error waiting for pipe client connect: " + e.Message);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, that link describes my problem to a T (including why it works in my test code and not my GUI app). Now there's almost certainly a better or "more correct" way of doing this, as I'm new to async/await; so in order to make the method synchronous I am leaving my code as is, but preventing the deadlock by adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` to the end of `await pipe.WaitForConnectionAsync(cts.Token)` so it executes the remainder on the thread pool, and it works!