# Parllel Foreach vs Async Foreach for DB calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, foreach

I have scenario where I have to call a same database stored procedure for each item in a list. I don't want to use foreach as it will degrade the performance, Which will be best option parllel foeach or async/await foreach?

Below is sample code

```
public Task<List<object>> CallMethod()
{
    foreach(var obj in input)
    {
        List.Add(await Task.Run(() =>CallDatabase(obj)));
    }
   return List;
}

public CallDatabase(object)
{
    //Code to call DB 
}
```

All the objects received from the DB are independents.

After few research I am planning to use async calls, will this improve performance?

Comment: How would `async` help - don't you need to wait for the results to come back before you continue anyways?

Comment: No I don't have to wait for result. As soon as i get records from DB I will build object and add to list. Client will receive the list of the objects generated from DB. All objects are independent.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it's going to make any difference either way.  I assume you *still* need to wait for all results to be loaded, in which case `async` does not help, and your bottleneck will most likely be network I/O and server processing rather than local CPU, so parallelism will not help either.

That said, if you don't need the results of the query and don't care if there is an error, then `async` may help in a fire-and-forget scenario.

Your biggest bang for your buck may be to try and get multiple results in one query rather than firing off a bunch of individual queries.

Comment: Aren't you making assumptions about architecture here? The database server might be a powerful machine, or part of a cluster, with the queries not being locked by each other, in which case you might see a performance increase by running the queries in parallel.

Comment: Initial plan was to get everything in one DB call but that is not feasable given the complexity of the query,,

Comment: D Stanley, `WhenAll` let's you `await` many operations as shown in my post, but indeed it unlikely to speed things up if DB access is already maxes out usage of whatever resources (network, DB server,...).

Comment: @Ananke Yes I'm assuming that I/O is much more of a bottleneck than local CPU, which I think is reasonable, even in a clustered environment.  Parallel only helps in CPU-intensive operations by taking advantage of multiple local cores.

Answer (score 1):

Defintiely `Async`, as `Parallel.ForEach` is meant for compute intensive operations. It spreads over available core resources and orchestrates them accordingly. Async, instead, is meant for just this kind of operations: make a request to the service, go ahead and receive notification once resources requested before are available.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, What happens if i use parllel foreach for my scenario.. Will it block the next item to call database until 1st is done?

Comment: No, it will block single thread, which will wait you DB call being complete. so your program will run smoothly, but using threads for these kind of things is a waste of resources.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach is not ideal for IO bound operations because each thread will block, waiting for the data. If async operations are available for calling your database then it is better to make use of these.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly comment to [D Stanley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32951128/477420) - switching to parallel/async code unlikely to improve performance.

If your main concern is responsiveness/scalability - async would be better as generally DB access is IO-bound operation. It also allows to pick between sequential and parallel processing (i.e. in case your DB layer does not support concurrent requests on same connection for some reason). Additionally with `async` it is easier to get synchronization right for updating UI/request if you use default synchronization context.

Sequential: it will run about as long as non-async solution, but the thread will be free to perform other activities at the same time (for UI applications like WinForms/WPF) or process requests (ASP.Net).

```
async public Task<ResultType> CallMethodAsync()
{
    foreach(var obj in input)
    {
        var singleResult = await CallDatabaseAsync(obj);
        // combine results if needed
    }
    // return combined results    
}
```

Parallel: will run all requests at the same time, will likely be faster than sequential solution.

```
async public Task<ResultType> CallMethodAsync()
{
    List<Task<SingleResultType>> tasks = new List<Task<SingleResultType>>();
    foreach(var obj in input)
    {
        tasks.Add(await CallDatabaseAsync(obj));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    foreach(SingleResultType result in tasks.Select(t=>t.Result))
    {
        // combine results if needed
    }
    // return combined results    
}
```

Note that `async` generally requires all your code to be asynchronous - so if you converting just small piece of code to run in parallel `Parallel.ForEach` may be easier solution as it does not involve dealing with [await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i am planning to implement something like this. i think performance might increase a bit because all the objects returned from database are independent..

Comment: What is difference between When.All and Task.Run??

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a solution; not sure if this async or will improve performance a bit or not, I am very new to async so don't have much idea.

```
 public static async Task<List<Response>> Execute(Request objInput)
 {
       List<Response> objList = new List<Response>();
       foreach (object obj in objInput.objs)
        {
            objList.Add(await Task.Run(() =>GetDataFromDB(obj)));
        }
  return objList;
 }


  private static object GetDataFromDB(object obj)
  {
       //Call DB and build the object
  }
```

If this is not the correct way to implement async, then please offer other ideas.

Comment: I would think you'd want your `GetDataFromDB` to also be `async` and then it should call `async` methods for communicating with the DB.  Then you don't need the `Task.Run` in your `Execute` method.

Comment: I read somewhere that await (Task.Run) will call async. is that correct?

Comment: The idea of `async` is that something is doing IO and you want to free up threads while that IO occurs.  When you use `await Task.Run` you are just  pushing the "waiting" from one thread to another.

Comment: If you don't mind can you post one example of how to do that? this things are very confusing.