# Program hangs when calling REST API from Xamarin PCL

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.android, portable-class-library

I have the following code in my Xamarin PCL

```
    public Product Product(int id)
    {

        var product = Get<Product>(endpoint + "?id=" + id).Result;
        return product;
    }

    static async Task<T> Get<T>(string endpoint)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content));
        }
    }
```

My program just hangs at this line

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
```

No exception thrown.

I execute the same code in a console app, and it works fine.

The only difference I could see is that in my console app, I'm referencing `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` in the `lib\net45` folder. In my Xamarin PCL project, I'm referencing `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` in the `lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+wpa81` folder. I tried referencing the dll in the `lib\portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50` folder, same result.

I'm using Json 8.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code hangs because you are accessing `Result` property of a Task. You should instead use `await` keyword to get the result from the Task.

The deadlock happens because the synchronization context is captured by two different threads. See this answer for more details: [await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13140963/239438)

It works in console application because `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null so there is no deadlock happening. See this post for more details: [Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You are forcing the Async operation to be run in a synchronous method by accessing Result property

```
public async Task<Product> Product(int id)
{

    var product = await Get<Product>(endpoint + "?id=" + id);
    return product;
}
```

Modifying Product Method as above will fix it.