# Why does this code deadlocks on WinForm, but works in ConsoleApplication?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Consider this simple `async` method:

```
private static async Task<int> foo()
{
    await Task.Delay(1500);
    return 1;
}
```

If I do the following in a `WinForm` application, as I expect, it deadlocks

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fooTask = foo();
    fooTask.Wait();
}
```

However, if I do the same in a `ConsoleApplication` it works (doesn't deadlock)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fooTask = foo();
    fooTask.Wait();
}
```

Why this happens? Shouldn't the `Task` be unable to continue because the context thread is "blocked"?

Comment: context != thread. See [This Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/gg598924.aspx) for lots of details.

Comment: You also may have more info in the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock and the blog post mentionned in it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think that I still don't understand the concept of context, but is it correct if I say that basically a `SynchronizationContext` decides which `Thread` will continue a suspended `work unit`?

Comment: @Niitaku I think that linked question is more about the difference between `Wait`/`await`

Comment: @MatteoUmili That's why I didn't flag as duplicate. I was commenting to target [this blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) mentioned in the answer that explain why a `Task.Wait` can deadlock in a SynchronizationContext (scroll to _"What Causes the Deadlock"_ part).

Comment: Could someone please explain me the downvotes?

Comment: The context has to schedule the work to happen somewhere. Some contexts nominate one thread as being special and arrange for all work to happen on that thread. But other contexts could do whatever they want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because WinForms applications have a [SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx). That means, whenever you await an asynchronous operation, the operation will be continued (by default) on the same SynchronizationContext.

You can change this behavior by calling [ConfigureAwait(false)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will not capture the SynchronizationContext.

In your case, this SynchronizationContext is for the UI thread. Thus, when you execute

> await Task.Delay(1500)

The continuation code will be executed on the UI thread. But in the same time, the UI thread is blocked because of the

> fooTask.Wait()

ConsoleApplications however don't have SynchronizationContext, thus the continuation of asynchronous operations might be executed on different threads.