# SQLite collation attribute

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm using a sqlite database on my Xamarin app and i'm tring to set collation attribute on my data model

```
public class Customer
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Collation("NOCASE")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

but I do not found anywhere which value must I set into collation attribute to control case sensitive / case insensitive collation

this is my test code:

```
var dbfile = DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper().GetLocalFilePath("data.db");

db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbfile);
db.CreateTableAsync<Customer>().Wait();
var result = await db.Table<Customer>().OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToListAsync();
```

**expected result: case insensitive order in name column,**

**actual result: the order is case sensitive.**

Comment: 1)
var sortedWords = words.OrderBy(a => a.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

2)
sortedWords = words.OrderBy(a => a.Name, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

3)
sortedWords = words.OrderBy(a => a.Name, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

Comment: sorry but I did not found an overload of method OrderBy where StringComparer could be specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, after the attribute

```
[Collation("NOCASE")]
```

is added, then the table must be dropped and re-receated. Usually sqlite automatically update the table after a change when the command

```
db.CreateTableAsync<Customer>().Wait()
```

is executed, but in this case the drop / delete table is required.

Comment: Please use `await db.CreateTableAsync...` instead of `.Wait()` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13140963/121309