# Why does await block Dispatcher.Invoke?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, dispatcher

Why does it block? I know a solution with Dispatcher.PushFrame() but still. Is it the issue of a classic "Don't Block on Async Code" type?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test().Wait();
    }

    static async Task Test()
    {
        var disp = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        var t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            disp.Invoke(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("works");
            });
        });
        await t.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

UPD: Now it waits synchronously on the main thread, and uses threadpool dispatcher and still blocks.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async() => await Test()).Wait();
    }

    static async Task Test()
    {
        var disp = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        var t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            disp.Invoke(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("works");
            });
        });
        await t.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock

Comment: ` Test().Wait();` is blocking not `await`

Comment: since `Wait()` does not wait a task that run on background thread, so when `await `  happend, Main thread is blocked , and so every thead is blocked

Comment: Ok, i can rearange example a little, now i'm waiting sychronously on the main thread, while using dispatcher from the threadpool:    static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   Task.Run(async() => await Test()).Wait();
  }

  static async Task Test()
  {
   var disp = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
   var t = Task.Run(() =>
   {
    disp.Invoke(() =>
    {
     Console.WriteLine("works");
    });
   });
   await t.ConfigureAwait(false);
  }

Comment: I think there is the same issue with main thead,  when u `await`  , the `Dispatcher` thead is blocked!   you should put it inside Task.Run

Comment: @John please see update, i'm running it in Task.Run and still blocks.

Comment: @IgorGnilitsky  It's not in the `t` task,  and when u await `t` ,  current thead blocked (I mean `test` task's thread)

Comment: @John no i still do not get how await can block the thread. could you provide a code example of what you mean?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/ServerTests/issues/86#issuecomment-311243139

Comment: This test code does not have a functional Dispatcher.  The Application.Run() call is crucial to allow it to do what it needs to do.  Ignoring this need can only produce deadlock.

Comment: @HansPassant, do you mean in this case dispatcher doesn't even run anything? I actually have a workaround based on Dispatcher.PushFrame fucntion (can't post teh code unfortunatelly) that if called instead of await t.ConfigureAwait(false); works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I try this code , and it work. The problem is the how `Dispatche` work, I think it need a thread that is not stopped and not sleeped  and not busy for runing other code .

```
static Dispatcher dispatcher;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    Task.Run(async () => await Test());  //.Wait();

    while (true)
    {
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(new DispatcherFrame());
    }
}

static async Task Test()
{
    //var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    var t = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dispatcher.Thread.ThreadState);
        dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("works");
        });
    });
    await t; ;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks that will work, we have a solution based on PushFrame. Just wanted to know why await doesn't work.

Comment: `await` doesn't work because when u `await`, the current thread that is running need to "pause" and release this thread to threadpool (not happend in every time, only happend when it switch thread, and it does for this case : `Task.Run`), that cause dispatcher can not  run, and because that  the await  method will never finish .