# use multi threading and return different types from different tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have two tasks that I need to run, they are both separate tasks and take a little while to run.

Rather than running them one after the other I would like to use multi threading.

Both tasks return lists of different types.

Say the first list is of type *Book* & my list is bkList and my second list of type *Song* and is called sgList.

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[2];

tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(SomeProcess);
tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(AnotherProcess);

        try
        {
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);

            // do stuff

        }
        catch(AggregateException ex)
        {
            ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
        }
```

How do I ensure both tasks have completed? My above code I believe works  in that it would wait until both tasks have run. However I don't know how to get the returned lists? i.e.

```
 List<Book> bkList = tasks[0].Result;
 List<Song> sgList = tasks[1].Result;
```

**Update**

Sorry should have said the two lines above was me guessing at the answer. However there is no *Result* property when I type it in.

> Task does not contain a definition for Result

Comment: you answered your question yourself already

Comment: Are you saying your final snippet there doesn't work?

Comment: @itsme86 sorry yes I should have been clearer. There is no .Result option

Comment: Whilst that should work, you should make the method this code is running inside of `async` and use `await Task.WhelAll(tasks);` instead

Comment: Side note: make sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock as you used `.Wait` and `.Result` in your sample.