# Breakpoint not hitting after .Wait()

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

i have a .net web api 2 method where i am trying to have some part of my code do something in a separate thread, however after I call the .Wait() method on the task it never hits the next line. I must be overlooking something, but I can't seem to find it. Here's a very simple version of the issue. The line Ok() never gets hit. Any suggestions?

```
public IHttpActionResult Get() {

    var attachTask = AttachNewTasksAsync();

    //do something else

    attachTask.Wait();

    return Ok();
}

public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task AttachNewTasksAsync()
{
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(10000);
}
```

Comment: `.Wait()` in the main context will deadlock ASP.NET applications

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock

Comment: Possible duplicate of [await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock)

Comment: Why are you doing `.Wait()` instead of making the action async and awaiting it properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deadlock. Your main thread is waiting for `attachTask` to finish and `attachTask`  cannot finish, because it is waiting for main thread.

Either add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to `Task.Delay` or do it properly and await `attachTask`

This is how it should be written:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get() {

    var attachTask = AttachNewTasksAsync();

    //do something else

    await attachTask;

    return Ok();
}
```

How to ensure that deadlock will not happen even if someone waits for it synchronously? Use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task AttachNewTasksAsync()
{
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(10000).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

There is probably nothing I can write, that isn't already covered by Stephen Cleary's blog, so I will just leave this [link](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) here.

Comment: This is correct blocking the thread explicitly in ASP.Net can lead to deadlock

Comment: Great answer! also i needed to use up my daily vote limit

Comment: Even `ConfigureAwait(false)` may not help, that's not a hard constraint its a soft indicator to configure the `await`

Comment: sweet thanks, it was quite hard to find a decent example where syntaxes aren't mixed up