# ConfigureAwait(false) loses the context of an object

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, async-await, httphandler

In my program, i'm making a request, and I log the request and the response.
But using the `ConfigureAwait(false)`, may loses the context of my `"logger"` object, which is logging the request in one file, and the response in another file.

```
try
{
    logger.VerboseRequest(tokenParameters.Endpoint, payloadJson, options);
    serializedResponse = await httpHandler.PostAsync<string>
                        (tokenParameters.Endpoint, payloadJson, options, cts.Token)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    throw new TokenTimeoutException();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.Error(String.Format("Error when posting to Endpoint: {0}",ex.Message));
    throw;
}
```

Any Idea why this is happening? Or what to do to avoid it?

By removing the `ConfigureAwait(false)` I may have TimeOut problems, so that is not an option.

Comment: Ehmm.... I thought that that behavior is by design....

Comment: @PoulBak Why in the world would you explicitly not run the continuation in the current context only to then explicitly schedule the continuation to run in that context?

Comment: `By removing the ConfigureAwait(false) I may have TimeOut problems` Are you waiting synchronously on a task somewhere? If so, that's the issue you should be fixing

Answer (score 1):

That's by design behavior, so you must ask yourself: ***"Am I doing this the  right way?"***

There are various way's to overcome that problem. If you want a loggable fire-and-forget async call, you can wrap it in a call like this. But beware, the task runs probably on a different context, so you might not have access to typical context-bound variables, like your current HttpContext (and stuff like that).

```
Task.Run(async () => 
{
    try
    {
        logger.VerboseRequest(tokenParameters.Endpoint, payloadJson, options);
        serializedResponse = await httpHandler.PostAsync<string>
                                 (tokenParameters.Endpoint, payloadJson, options, cts.Token);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        throw new TokenTimeoutException();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(String.Format("Error when posting to Endpoint: {0}",ex.Message));
        throw;
    }
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

---

Or even better: wrap it in a function

```
async Task DoStuff()
{
    try
    {
        logger.VerboseRequest(tokenParameters.Endpoint, payloadJson, options);
        serializedResponse = await httpHandler.PostAsync<string>
                                 (tokenParameters.Endpoint, payloadJson, options, cts.Token);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        throw new TokenTimeoutException();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(String.Format("Error when posting to Endpoint: {0}",ex.Message));
        throw;
    }
}
```

And where your current code is:

```
async Task WhereYouAreDoingStuff()
{
    DoStuff().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: First, I'm sorry about the bad formulated question. I'm new at async/await calls and I don't understand it very well. 
I Tried the approach you suggested, but I'm still getting a deadlock, if I don't use the configureAwait(False) in the HttpHandler call

Comment: @FernandoAugustoStavroDuarte: No worries; Do you use `.Wait()` or `.Result` somewhere? If you can show more of your code we'll get more information about the context. About async/await and deadlocks; this might help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock#13140963

Comment: Hi! I still haven't found the problem, but i've talked to my boss, and this is an expected behaviour, defined with the client. Thanks for your Help!