# Http Async Post in c#,Raspberry Pi ,data not post

Tags: c#, async-await

The HTTP async method not working and the data never post when I run this in raspberry pi. The distance monitoring method still running but just the data doesn't post [Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhddo.png)

```
IUltrasonicRangerSensor sensor = DeviceFactory.Build.UltraSonicSensor(Pin.DigitalPin8);
private int distance = 200;

int count = 0;
ILed ledRed = DeviceFactory.Build.Led(Pin.DigitalPin5);
ILed ledGreen = DeviceFactory.Build.Led(Pin.DigitalPin6);

private void Sleep(int NoOfMs)
{
    Task.Delay(NoOfMs).Wait();
}

private async void startDistanceMonitoring()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    int distanceRead = 200;
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        count++;
        distanceRead = sensor.MeasureInCentimeters();
        if (distanceRead < 200 && distanceRead > 0)
            distance = distanceRead;
        await sendtoapi();
    }
}

private async Task sendtoapi()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "userName", "qwee" }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://google.com", content);

        Sleep(10000);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}

public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance) 
{ 
    startDistanceMonitoring();
    Sleep(300);
    Debug.WriteLine("count = " + count + " ,distance=" + distance);
    while (true)
    {
        if (distance >= 150)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("EMPTY LOT");
            Sleep(1000);
            ledGreen.ChangeState(SensorStatus.On);
            ledRed.ChangeState(SensorStatus.Off);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No [images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), please. Images are surprisingly hard to compile and run. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54248776/edit).

Comment: I have tested your code with a [webhook testing service](https://webhook.site/#/7f7d1414-2ce8-47a8-82d1-e5bf31c7bc71/538c930d-da4b-4bb1-859e-68c47f6ba23a/1), and as you can see the post is successful. It may be because you're using `.Wait()` with `Task.Delay`, which could be causing a deadlock?

Comment: I suspect your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock). The deadlock is basically caused by the caller waiting for the task, and the task waiting for the caller.

Comment: Do I just remove the private void Sleep(int NoOfMs) method?

Comment: That would probably be a good idea. I'm not sure what you're waiting 10 seconds for, really.

Comment: I remove the method and the data still not posting. I'm sending to azure database

Comment: Please learn about `async` deadlocks. You are calling Sleep in multiple places, and probably not calling the async methods up the chain correctly. Your post method itself does work if called correctly.

Comment: even though i remove the sleep method, the data still not posting

Comment: I call the method in startdistanceMonitoring with   await sendtoapi();

Comment: And you removed all instances of `Sleep`, replacing them with `await Task.Delay(...)`?

Comment: ya,except in the run method

Comment: _"except in the run method"_. Remove it there.

Comment: still not posting

Comment: and the status of the sensor will be always the same

Comment: Sorry. I can't help you. I can confirm that your `sendtoapi()` definitely works, provided you remove the `Sleep` code. If you have a deadlock somewhere, that's up to you to fix.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, i will figure out the rest myself

Comment: There is a **lot** wrong here. You calling async code and not awaiting it, you also have `async void` methods, these should only ever be used for async event handlers. These should be `async Task`. your calling `Task.Delay(NoOfMs).Wait();` which is a blocking call in a non async context. Basically there isn't much of this code that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `async`/`await` you basically want to make all(most) of your methods work in an `async`/`await` manner. At the moment your mixing async and non async method calls. [This is called blocking in an `async` context and it should be avoided](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), not least of which because it can lead to deadlocks. I'd suggest you have a read though [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

In general (and to simplify the problem somewhat) **all** your methods should have the signature

```
public async Task method()
{

}
```

and **all** your methods should be called:

```
await method();
```

### Here are a couple of things your doing wrong

```
private async void startDistanceMonitoring()
```

Never use `async void` (these are for async event handlers only)

```
private void Sleep(int NoOfMs)
{
    Task.Delay(NoOfMs).Wait();
}
```

this is blocking, this should be

```
private async Task Sleep(int NoOfMs)
{
    await Task.Delay(NoOfMs);
}
```

When you call:

```
startDistanceMonitoring();
```

`startDistanceMonitoring` is an `async` method, yet your not awaiting it. So your program may very well terminate before it's completed. This should be:

```
await startDistanceMonitoring();
```

You do this incorrectly all over this block of code. **Always call `async` methods with an `await`**.

Your entry method isn't `async`, `public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)` should be `public async Task Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)`

Comment: i cant call the await startdistanceMonitoring() in public void run as it is a public void not a async method,do i need to change it to async also?

Comment: Yes you do. That's what I'm saying