# How to resolve Tasks hanging c#?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

While going over some code in a console application, I saw the nested Task.WhenAll in the `SecondInitialize` function. I decided to test this function with a large Locations List and see how it reacted.

What I saw is that with about 100 locations, 100*100 = 10,000 `Calculate` calls, the `t.Wait()` inside of `Start` takes about 60 seconds to return or sometimes just hang completely. If i try to click `Break All` the console application doesn't even respond to my click and visual studio crashes.

When using my 'Easier to read version' inside of `SecondInitialize`, it also takes a while to return. Consistent behavior.

Now the weird part is, whenever I use the debugger and put a breakpoint inside of the `SecondInitialize` and then hit continue, it will finish in about 5-7 seconds.

So my question is, why is it hanging taking a long time normally when I see it being faster when I debug inside that function? Another question is whether or not the use of `Tasks` is being utilized correctly

```
public void Start()
{
    var t = CacheInitialize(locations, CancellationToken.None);
    t.Wait();
}

public Task CacheInitialize(IList<Location> locations, CancellationToken token)
{
    return SecondInitialize(locations, token);
}

public async Task SecondInitialize(IList<Location> locations, CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(locations.Select(first =>
    {
        return Task.WhenAll(locations.Where(second => !second.Equals(first)).Select(second =>
        {
            return Calculate(first, second, token);
        }));
    }));

    //Easier to read version of ^
    //var tasks = locations.SelectMany(first => locations.Where(second => !second.Equals(first)).Select(second =>
    //{
    //  return Calculate(first, second, token);
    //}));
    //await Task.WhenAll(tasks);


    //No Tasks.
    //for (int x = 0; x < locations.Length; x++)
    //{
    //    for (int y = 0; y < locations.Length; y++)
    //    {
    //        if (x == y)
    //            continue;
    //        await Calculate(locations[x], locations[y], token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    //    }
    //}
}

public async Task<TripLength> Calculate(Location start, Location finish, CancellationToken token)
{
    if (start == finish)
        return TripLength.Zero;

    var parameters = new RouteParameters
    {
        Coordinates = new []
        {
            new Coordinate(start.Latitude, start.Longitude),
            new Coordinate(finish.Latitude, finish.Longitude)
        }
    };

    var route = await RunRoute(parameters, token);

    return ToTripLength(route);
}


protected Task<RouteResult> RunRoute(RouteParameters routeParams, CancellationToken token)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var routingTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            RouteResult routeResults;
            var status = _routeService.Route(routeParams, out routeResults);
            return routeResults;
        }, token);
    return await routingTask.ConfigureAwait(false);

    }, token);
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve], including the `Route` method.

Comment: Explain what you're trying to do, not how you think the solution would look. If I didn't work for an OTA I'd have a real hard time guessing what you want to do. I can't read the code but I suspect you want to speed up mapping search results to your own objects.

Comment: BTW what is `_routeService` and what does `_routeService.Route` do? It matters a *lot*. Different APIs are used for data parallelism (eg PLINQ), different once are used when you want to make multiple concurrent calls to a remote service (eg ActionBlock/TransformBlock)

Comment: First, the API meant for data parallelism is PLINQ. Instead of using raw tasks and using multiple nested `Task.WhenAll` statements to get the results, you could write a LINQ query to map one set of results to another and "just" put an `AsParallel()` statement near the top. Instead of having eg 100 tasks trying to get scheduled on 4 cores you could have 4 tasks each with its own partition of 25 data points to calculate

Comment: Second, calling a remote service is an *async* operation that shouldn't waste tasks. Making 100 concurrent calls to a third-party service will probably get you throttled too. That's where TransformBlock comes in, allowing you to make calls using a specific DoP.

Comment: Third, the code is overconvoluted, probably because it blocks itself and then tries to fix the problem by adding more code. The entire `runroute` method can be replaced with a single `RunRoute(RouteParameters routeParams, CancellationToken token)=>Task.Run(()=>_routeService,Route(routeParams,var out ruteResults); return results;},token);`. No need for the nested tasks or `ConfigureAwait`s

Comment: This smells like an XY problem.

Comment: @IanKemp yes and no. Once you read the code you realize it's trying to calculate lenghts between destinations - that's the X. Using raw tasks instead of a higher level library is the Y. Given that `100` is a standard result size when searching for air tickets, one could even suspect the OP is trying to create multi-hop routes from single segment trips. That would be Problem W or even Problem V - you can't just brute force the travelling salesman problem and calculating 10K routes is a lot cheaper once you find a way to eliminate invalid results

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be how to calculate routes from all trips connecting a set of locations (origins and destinations?) and calculate the length (cost?) of each route. The expensive work seems to be the call to `_routeService.Route` and `ToTripLength`.

Calculating 10K combinations from 100 locations is trivial and doesn't need parallelization. A simple LINQ query would work:

```
var combinations=( from start in locations
                   from finish in locations
                   where start!=finish
                   select (start,finish))
                 .ToArray();
```

What happens after that depends on what `_routeService.Route` does. If it's a local library, this is a data parallelism problem that tries to calculate 10K data points in the most efficient manner. That can be handled with [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/parallel-linq-plinq?view=netframework-4.7.2)

If it's a call to an external service it's a *concurrency* problem that shouldn't waste CPU time waiting for 10K remote requests to respond.

Assuming `_routeService.Route` is a local libary, one can use PLINQ. A couple of helper methods will make writing the query easier though :

```
RouteParameters locationsToParams((Location start,Location finish) combination)
{
    return new RouteParameters {
        Coordinates = new[]
        {
            new Coordinate( start.Latitude, start.Longitude ),
            new Coordinate( finish.Latitude, finish.Longitude )
        }
    };
}

RouteResult  callRoute(RouteParameters routeParams)
{
    _routeService.Route(routeParams, out var routeResults);
    return routeResults;
}

var tripLengths = from cmb in combinations.AsParallel()
                  let routeParams=locationsToParams(cmb)
                  let result=callRoute(routeParams)
                  select ToTripLength(result);
var finalResults = tripLengths.ToArray();
```

[AsParallel()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel?view=netframework-4.7.2) will take the input IEnumerable, in this case combinations, partition it to as many partitions as there are cores and then use *one* worker task per partition. Each partition's data is fed to its worker task, minimizing the synchronization cost.

This could be used as a quick and rather dirty way to make 10K remote requests, as each call to `Route` will run on one of the worker tasks. This is wasteful because it blocks a task only to wait for a response. [WithDegreeOfParallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq?view=netframework-4.7.2#degree-of-parallelism) could be used to use more worker tasks than cores, but this still wastes CPU time waiting for a response. Blocking calls start with a SpinWait before a thread is suspended, which means a blocking call to a remote service can use a CPU core while doing nothing. This can *seriously* harm scalability on a server environment.

```
var tripLengths = from cmb in combinations.AsParallel()
                                          .WithDegreeOfParalellism(10)
                  let routeParams=locationsToParams(cmb)
                  let result=callRoute(routeParams)
                  select ToTripLength(result);
var finalResults = tripLengths.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your example is not complete and can’t be compiled it’s kind of hard to see what exactly you are trying to do.

But as far as I can tell there are several problems:

1. Calling `Wait` (or `Result`) on a Task [can lead to deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13140963/1320170).
   Using `ConfigureAwait( false )` will help avoid such issues but can’t eliminate all of them.
   So best always await a Task when you want to access it’s result.
2. I don’t see what you are trying to accomplish with nesting `Task.WhenAll` within `Task.WhenAll`.
   `WhenAll` returns a single Task which you can just await without `Task.WhenAll`.
   Each Task you create will add some performance overhead, so you should try to create as few task as possible.
3. Using `Task.Run` with an async delegate to await another Task(created by `Task.Run`) makes no sense, you are creating more Tasks than you need.
   You can just await a single Task.Run

I tried to create a working example (it won’t do any work) based on your code to show what you should change.
Please note async Main method is only available in C# 7.1 or above.

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main( String[] args )
    {
        var foo = new Foo();

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        await foo.Start();

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed {sw.Elapsed} {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public async Task CacheInitialize( IList<Location> locations, CancellationToken token ) =>
        await SecondInitialize( locations, token )
            .ConfigureAwait( false );

    public async Task<TripLength> Calculate( Location start, Location finish, CancellationToken token )
    {
        if ( start == finish )
            return TripLength.Zero;

        var parameters = new RouteParameters
        {
            Coordinates = new[]
            {
                new Coordinate( start.Latitude, start.Longitude ),
                new Coordinate( finish.Latitude, finish.Longitude )
            }
        };

        var route = await RunRoute( parameters, token );

        return new TripLength();
    }

    public async Task SecondInitialize( IList<Location> locations, CancellationToken token )
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>( locations.Count );

        foreach ( var outer in locations )
        foreach ( var inner in locations )
        {
            if ( inner.Equals( outer ) )
                continue;

            tasks.Add( Calculate( outer, inner, token ) );
        }

        await Task.WhenAll( tasks );
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        var locations = new List<Location>();
        await CacheInitialize( locations, CancellationToken.None )
            .ConfigureAwait( false );
    }

    protected async Task<RouteResult> RunRoute( RouteParameters routeParams, CancellationToken token )
    {
        return await Task
                     .Run( () =>
                           {
                               //RouteResult routeResults;
                               //var status = _routeService.Route( routeParams, out routeResults );
                               //return routeResults;
                               return new RouteResult();
                           },
                           token )
                     .ConfigureAwait( false );
    }
}

public class Coordinate
{
    public Double Latitude { get; }
    public Double Longitude { get; }
    public Coordinate( Double latitude, Double longitude )
    {
        Latitude = latitude;
        Longitude = longitude;
    }
}
public class RouteParameters
{
    public Coordinate[] Coordinates { get; set; }
}
public class TripLength
{
    public static TripLength Zero = new TripLength();
}
public class RouteResult
{
}
public class Location
{
    public Double Latitude { get; }
    public Double Longitude { get; }
}
```