# populate 2 lists using parallelism

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have 2 long running methods that get data from external sources and return the results as lists:

```
public static class Helper1
{
    public static List<X> GetStuff()
    {
        // some long running stuff
    }
}

public static class Helper2
{
    public static List<Y> GetStuff()
    {
        // some long running stuff
    }
}
```

I would like to run them in parallel rather than sequentially. My first attempt is:

var task1 = new Task>(() => Helper1.GetStuff());
var task2 = new Task>(() => Helper2.GetStuff());

```
var whenAllTask = Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

task1.Start();
task2.Start();
```

Nothing seems to happen and I wonder how I can access the content of the lists afterwards (program continues sequentially). Thanks!

PS:

I am now using the following code, given Robin B's answer:

```
 var task1 = new Task<List<X>>(() => Helper1.GetStuff(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    var task2 = new Task<List<Y>>(() => Helper1.GetStuff(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

    var whenAllTask = Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).Wait();

    List<X> lst1 = task1.Result;
    List<Y> lst2 = task2.Result;
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens, It appears to be stuck.

PPS:

This seems to work for me:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<X>>(() => Helper1.GetStuff(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<Y>>(() => Helper2.GetStuff(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

var allTasks = new Task[] { task1, task2 };

Task.WaitAll(allTasks);

List<X> lst1 = task1.Result;
List<Y> lst2 = task2.Result;
```

Comment: `await whenAllTask;` to wait for the completion of `task1` and `task2`

Comment: I would also advise to specify the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` flag on creation, this will force the creation of a separate thread to run the task.

Comment: @Knoop thanks could you please provide example code? Thanks.

Comment: `t1` and `t2` are not defined. Are they related to this question? Also, the assignment for `task2` does not compile, since `Helper1.GetStuff` return a `List<X>`. Please use real code for samples.

Comment: @cs0815 it's a flag you can pass to the `Task` constructor (or to `TaskFactory.StartNew` if you're using that). So an example would be `var task1 = new Task<List<X>>(() => Helper1.GetStuff(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);`

Comment: @RufusL sorry just spotted mistake and corrected

Comment: `var task2 = new Task<List<Y>>(() => Helper1.GetStuff());` - shouldn't this be `Helper2`?

Comment: @RufusL yes sorry corrected.

Answer (score 3):

`WhenAll` will wait for all given *running* tasks. So you will have to start them first.
Also If you use `Task<T>` you can retrieve the result of the Task after it has finished by reading the `Task<T>.Result` property.

You will also notice that `Task.WhenAll` will return an awaitable. So you will have to call `Wait()` there or you will just fire and forget.

Here is an example:

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      Task<List<int>> t1 = new Task<List<int>>(GetList);
      Task<List<int>> t2 = new Task<List<int>>(GetList);

      t1.Start();
      t2.Start();

      Task.WhenAll(t1, t2).Wait();

      Console.WriteLine("Both should have ended now");

      List<int> lst1 = t1.Result;
      List<int> lst2 = t2.Result;

      Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    public static List<int> GetList()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Started");

      Random rng = new Random();

      List<int> lst = new List<int>();

      for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
      {
        lst.Add(rng.Next());
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Ended");

      return lst;
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**
You might want to read up on `await` vs `Wait()`. I did imply by you saying the program continues sequentially that you are in purely synchronous context and just need to improve fetching performance. But if you call this Code from a UI Thread or similar beware that the `Wait()` call will block your UI thread. In this case using await would be the better option. ([await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock))

Comment: Thanks the code you provided works fine. However, it does not appear to work in my scenario, where I uses these static classes and methods. It just hangs. i put a break point into List<X> GetStuff() and it is not hit. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The cleaner way should be making your methods asynchronous so that they can be called asynchronously:

```
public static class Helper1
{
    public static Task<List<string>> GetStuffAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => new List<string>{"78", "98", "56",});
    }
}

public static class Helper2
{
    public static Task<List<int>> GetStuffAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6});
    }
}
```

Then call them like the following. The key here is the `await` keyword which tells the compiler that the tasks must be completed at this point.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var task1 = Helper1.GetStuff();
    var task2 = Helper2.GetStuff();
    
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

    Console.WriteLine(task1.Result);
    Console.WriteLine(task2.Result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<X>>(() => Helper1.GetStuff(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<Y>>(() => Helper2.GetStuff(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

var allTasks = new Task[] { task1, task2 };

Task.WaitAll(allTasks);

List<X> lst1 = task1.Result;
List<Y> lst2 = task2.Result;
```