# How to await task launched on Main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, async-await, task

There is something I can't understand with chaining tasks and executing tasks on Main Thread.

I need to chain 2 tasks when my model updates: (1)update then (2)check status.
So I use continueWith to achieve this :

```
// Update the model
Debug.WriteLine($"BaseModel<{typeof(T)}> - Launching Update Process");
Status = ModelStatus.Updating;
Task Update = Task.Run(() => UpdateDataSpeciliazed());
Debug.WriteLine($"BaseModel<{typeof(T)}> - Update Process Lauchned");

// And check if the status of the model is updated
Update.ContinueWith(antecedent =>
{
    lock (IsLocked)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"BaseModel<{typeof(T)}> - Checking ModelStatus ({Status})");

        // UpdateDataSpeciliazed must update the status accordingly
        if (Status == ModelStatus.Updating)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"BaseModel<{typeof(T)}> - UpdateDataAsync - ModelStatus not updated");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        Debug.WriteLine($"BaseModel<{typeof(T)}> - ModelStatus Checked");
    }
});
```

When the function `UpdateDataSpeciliazed` of the derived class is simple (no child task), the process behave like expected. But when `UpdateDataSpeciliazed` launch some actions on the Main Thread (like below), the `ContinueWith` do not wait until completion of those actions, even if I ask to await them ?!? See order of execution below.

```
protected override async void UpdateDataSpeciliazed()
{
    _Data.Clear();
    Debug.WriteLine($"DaysPrestasService - UpdateDataSpeciliazed");

    await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() => {
        Debug.WriteLine($"DaysPrestasService - Transferd to UI Thread");

        // Read and add DATA here

        Status = ModelStatus.Filled;
        Debug.WriteLine($"DaysPrestasService - Endof UI Thread");
    });

    Debug.WriteLine($"DaysPrestasService - UpdateDataSpeciliazed ended");
}
```

> BaseModel<Data.DaysPrestasCard> - Launching Async Update
> BaseModel<Data.DaysPrestasCard> - Launching Update Process
> BaseModel<Data.DaysPrestasCard> - Update Process Lauchned
> BaseModel<Data.DaysPrestasCard> - Launching error checking set up
> DaysPrestasService - UpdateDataSpeciliazed
> BaseModel<Data.DaysPrestasCard> - Checking ModelStatus (Updating)
> BaseModel<Data.DaysPrestasCard> - UpdateDataAsync- ModelStatus not updated
> DaysPrestasService - Transferd to UI Thread ---> DONE AFTER CHECK ?!?
> DaysPrestasService - Endof UI Thread ---> DONE AFTER CHECK ?!?
> DaysPrestasService - UpdateDataSpeciliazed ended ---> DONE AFTER CHECK ?!?

Can anybody tell me how to prevent `ContinueWith` to begin when execution in `UpdateDataSpeciliazed` jump to another thread ? It is strange for me because of the `await` before `Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync`

Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `async void` is not awaitable but if it was, you're anyway not awaiting it. Thus continuation runs before the method exit.

You may try sync-over-async call to update the UI:

```csharp
protected override void UpdateDataSpeciliazed()
{
    _Data.Clear();
    Debug.WriteLine($"DaysPrestasService - UpdateDataSpeciliazed");

    Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() => {
        Debug.WriteLine($"DaysPrestasService - Transferd to UI Thread");

        // Read and add DATA here

        Status = ModelStatus.Filled;
        Debug.WriteLine($"DaysPrestasService - Endof UI Thread");
    }).Wait();

    Debug.WriteLine($"DaysPrestasService - UpdateDataSpeciliazed ended");
}
```

Continuation will works the only after the method is finished.

Or as alternative way: are you're able to change the signature of `UpdateDataSpeciliazed()` to `async Task`?

Comment: Thanks. That's the difference :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock

Comment: @Belight yes, there's an improtant difference. But you're runnung it on a separate Thread, not on the same. Thus `Wait()` here is safe thing. Finally the above suggestion is not the only and probably not the best way to solve.

Comment: I suppose in this case I can block the thread of UpdateDataSpeciliazed with .Wait() without slowndown as I know that is runs on a specific thread ?

Comment: Oups already answered .. Sorry