# Xamarin Forms (DisplayAlert): Not displaying and blocking physical phone

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Weird situation. DisplayAlert, in a XF app, is working in the emulator, in a Huawei Y9 (Android 9), but not in a Huawei Y9 Prime (Android 10). Is not poping and freezes the app.

The code to show it:

```
if (LocalSession.Device.IDDevice == 0) // Does not exist as registered device
{
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
   {
      DisplayAlert("Atención", "No existe el dispositivo en el sistema. Consulte al administrador. IMEI:" + LocalSession.IMEI, "Aceptar").Wait();
   });
}
```

Also tested without the `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` and still not working.

Any direction will be appreciated.

**HUAWEI Y9 Prime - EMUI -10.0.0.427**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is highly likely that calling `.Wait()` will result in the UI thread being blocked and cause the deadlock.

There are lots of good answers on here already on this topic (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13140963/32348)

You should try using `await` instead:

```cs
if (LocalSession.Device.IDDevice == 0) // Does not exist as registered device
{
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
   {
      await DisplayAlert("Atención", "No existe el dispositivo en el sistema. Consulte al administrador. IMEI:" + LocalSession.IMEI, "Aceptar");
   });
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you @Bijington

Answer (score 1):

The app freezes because you are using .Wait() instead of await. I would try it like this:
`await DisplayAlert("Atención", "No existe el dispositivo en el sistema. Consulte al administrador. IMEI:" + LocalSession.IMEI, "Aceptar");`

If the Popup still doesn’t appear, you can try opening it from the current MainPage like this:
`await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Atención", "No existe el dispositivo en el sistema. Consulte al administrador. IMEI:" + LocalSession.IMEI, "Aceptar");`