# loop every minute using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops

Good Day!

How to loop every minute using C#.

In my case I'm using while but I set only in bool because I don't know how to loop every minute.

This is the example code

```
 bool status = true;
 while (status)
            {
// Query to check the status of the Job

            string check_Jobs = "CREATE TABLE #list_running_SQL_jobs (     job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL   , last_run_date INT NOT NULL   , last_run_time INT NOT NULL   , next_run_date INT NOT NULL   , next_run_time INT NOT NULL   , next_run_schedule_id INT NOT NULL   , requested_to_run INT NOT NULL   , request_source INT NOT NULL   , request_source_id sysname NULL   , running INT NOT NULL   , current_step INT NOT NULL   , current_retry_attempt INT NOT NULL   , job_state INT NOT NULL );  DECLARE @sqluser NVARCHAR(128)       , @is_sysadmin INT;  SELECT @is_sysadmin = ISNULL(IS_SRVROLEMEMBER(N'sysadmin'), 0);  DECLARE read_sysjobs_for_running CURSOR FOR     SELECT DISTINCT SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid)FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs; OPEN read_sysjobs_for_running; FETCH NEXT FROM read_sysjobs_for_running INTO @sqluser;  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN     INSERT INTO #list_running_SQL_jobs     EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs @is_sysadmin, @sqluser;     FETCH NEXT FROM read_sysjobs_for_running     INTO @sqluser; END;  CLOSE read_sysjobs_for_running; DEALLOCATE read_sysjobs_for_running;  SELECT j.name      , 'Enbld' = CASE j.enabled                      WHEN 0                          THEN 'no'                      ELSE 'YES'                  END      , '#Min' = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.start_execution_date, ISNULL(a.stop_execution_date, GETDATE()))      , 'Status' = CASE                       WHEN a.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL                           AND a.stop_execution_date IS NULL                           THEN 'Executing'                       WHEN h.run_status = 0                           THEN 'FAILED'                       WHEN h.run_status = 2                           THEN 'Retry'                       WHEN h.run_status = 3                           THEN 'Canceled'                       WHEN h.run_status = 4                           THEN 'InProg'                       WHEN h.run_status = 1                           THEN 'Success'                       ELSE 'Idle'                   END      , r.current_step      , spid = p.session_id      , owner = ISNULL(SUSER_SNAME(j.owner_sid), 'S-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 1))) - CONVERT(BIGINT, 256) * CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 1)) / 256)) + '-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 4), 1)) / 256 + CONVERT(BIGINT, NULLIF(UNICODE(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 1)) / 256, 0)) - CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 1)) / 256)) + ISNULL('-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 5), 1))) + CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 6), 1))) * CONVERT(BIGINT, 65536) + CONVERT(BIGINT, NULLIF(SIGN(LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid)) - 6), -1)) * 0), '') + ISNULL('-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 7), 1))) + CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 8), 1))) * CONVERT(BIGINT, 65536) + CONVERT(BIGINT, NULLIF(SIGN(LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid)) - 8), -1)) * 0), '') + ISNULL('-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 9), 1))) + CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 10), 1))) * CONVERT(BIGINT, 65536) + CONVERT(BIGINT, NULLIF(SIGN(LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid)) - 10), -1)) * 0), '') + ISNULL('-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 11), 1))) + CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 12), 1))) * CONVERT(BIGINT, 65536) + CONVERT(BIGINT, NULLIF(SIGN(LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid)) - 12), -1)) * 0), '') + ISNULL('-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 13), 1))) + CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 14), 1))) * CONVERT(BIGINT, 65536) + CONVERT(BIGINT, NULLIF(SIGN(LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid)) - 14), -1)) * 0), ''))      , a.start_execution_date      , a.stop_execution_date      , t.subsystem      , t.step_name FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs j     LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #list_running_SQL_jobs) r         ON j.job_id = r.job_id     LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity a         ON j.job_id = a.job_id             AND a.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL             AND NOT EXISTS             (                 SELECT *                 FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity at                 WHERE at.job_id = a.job_id                     AND at.start_execution_date > a.start_execution_date             )     LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions p         ON p.program_name LIKE 'SQLAgent%0x%'             AND j.job_id = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 7, 2) + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 5, 2) + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 3, 2) + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 11, 2) + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 9, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 15, 2) + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 13, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 17, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 21, 12)     LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h         ON j.job_id = h.job_id             AND h.instance_id = a.job_history_id     LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps t         ON t.job_id = j.job_id             AND t.step_id = r.current_step where name='INVM_Export_Job' ORDER BY 1;  DROP TABLE #list_running_SQL_jobs";
            using (DataTable getStatus_Job = Utilities.SQL_Query(Globals.sSQLCS_FNS, check_Jobs, true, false)) // Connection to the database
            {
                if (getStatus_Job.Rows[0]["Status"].ToString() == "Success")
                {
                   
                    Globals.sSSIS_TDMAT_STATUS = "Success";
                    status = false;
                }
                else if (getStatus_Job.Rows[0]["Status"].ToString() == "FAILED")
                {
                    Globals.sSSIS_TDMAT_STATUS = "Failure";
                    status = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Globals.sSSIS_TDMAT_STATUS = "Ongoing Processing";
                    status = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the example image to check the status of the SSIS Job

[image]

This is the Utilities.cs that connects to the database

```
 public static DataTable SQL_Query(string sSQLCon, string sQry, Boolean isReturn, Boolean isRedirect = true, string sDataTableName = "DATA")
    {
        Globals.sError = "";
        DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(sSQLCon))
            {
                if (isReturn)
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlAdptr = new SqlDataAdapter(sQry, sqlCon))
                    {
                        sqlAdptr.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        sqlAdptr.Fill(dsData, sDataTableName);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sQry, sqlCon))
                    {
                        sqlCmd.Connection.Open();
                        sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        dsData.Tables.Add("DATA");
                    }
                }
                return dsData.Tables[0];
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Globals.sError = ex.Message;
            if (isRedirect)
                HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectToRoute("Error02");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want an event to occur every minute, why not use a timer?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using `System.Threading.Timer` along the lines of the code below, may need some modifications to work in your project.

A basic example which sets the time to wait to one minute with an optional constructor overload to change the wait time. An event for passing a status to the caller. For testing messages are sent to listeners on start and stopping the timer. Calling your operations and report status in `StatusCheck`.

```
using System.Threading;
using Timer = System.Threading.Timer;

namespace WorkingWithTimer.Classes
{
    public class Utilities
    {
        private static int _dueTime = 6000 * 10;
        private static Timer _workTimer;

        public delegate void MessageHandler(string message);
        public static event MessageHandler Message;

        private static void Initialize()
        {
            _workTimer = new Timer(Dispatcher);
            _workTimer.Change(_dueTime, Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        private static void Initialize(int dueTime)
        {
            _dueTime = dueTime;
            _workTimer = new Timer(Dispatcher);
            _workTimer.Change(_dueTime, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        private static void Dispatcher(object e)
        {
            StatusCheck();
            _workTimer.Dispose();
            Initialize();
        }

        public static void Start()
        {
            Initialize();
            Message?.Invoke("Started");
        }
        public static void Stop()
        {
            _workTimer.Dispose();
            Message?.Invoke("Stopped");
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Report to caller status e.g.
        /// Globals.sSSIS_TDMAT_STATUS = "Success";
        /// </summary>
        private static void StatusCheck()
        {
            Message?.Invoke("Performing work");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use [Task.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-6.0) to achieve this effect.

```
// wait for 60 seconds (60000 ms) and then resume processing
Task.Delay(60000).Wait();
```

Comment: Wasn't me but I'm pretty sure this will block the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13140963/1599751

Comment: Yes, the .Wait() call will block execution of the thread until the underlying thread timer for Task.Delay fires. However, calling .Wait() on a delay won't introduce a deadlock.

Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The issue I find with this is that it waits for 60 seconds, which might not be acceptable for what OP wants. I do also wonder why you prefer `Task.Delay(60000).Wait();` over `Thread.Sleep(60000);`?

Comment: It seems like the OP is looking to poll the database every minute to run a fast, read-only query to return the status of a job. Once that job completes, the OP wants to exit the loop. The loop should execute practically every 60 seconds unless the database server is resource constrained.

The OP could use a stopwatch to dynamically calculate the delay if it was important to kick off at exactly 60 seconds from start to start. However, that isn't what I read out of the post.

Thanks for the feedback regardless!

Comment: You should at least wrap it into a while-loop... A timer would be the better solution anyway.

Comment: Also, as a rule never call Wait() on a Task. Simply await it.

Comment: You can't await it if you aren't in an async function, though, @BionicCode.  Sometimes you have to call .Wait...

Comment: No, you don't. It's up to you to declare the method to be async. I really don't understand your comment.

Comment: In older language versions (maybe 7.2 and before if memory serves), Main cannot be async.  You cannot use the await keyword in that context.

Comment: First, I don't see any Main() here. Second, why would you want to run such code in your Main()? The simple fix is to not execute async code in your Main().

Comment: If the answer can be better, please feel free to edit it.  Without having the function definition, I didn't know if it was async or why / why not.  I just tried to contribute a helpful solution.