# Infinite download C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem downloading the file in my c# code.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DownloadFile().Wait();
}
private async Task DownloadFile()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Download");// appears
    HttpClient client = new();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("file");
    Debug.WriteLine("End download");// does not display
}
```

Thread stop after download but the app is not showing.

> Le thread 0x7d28 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
> Le thread 0x7998 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
> Le thread 0x269c s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
> Le thread 0x7e74 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
> Le thread 0x534c s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
> Le thread 0x77f0 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
> Le thread 0x70fc s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
> Le thread 0x7428 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
> Le thread 0x5628 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
> Le thread 0x788c s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
> Le thread 0x63f4 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Don't use `Wait()`. Use `await`. You can't use `await` in the constructor, but you can use it in `Form_Load`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13140963/2791540)

Comment: Don't use `Wait()` or `Result` in WinForms. Don't call that method from the Constuctor, subscribe to the `Load` event, make the handler `async` then `await DownloadFile()` -- Declare the HttpClient object as a static Field, dispose of it when the Form closes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Classic HttpClient bug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jpsanders/asp-net-do-not-use-task-result-in-main-context). When waited on the main thread causes deadlock. `ConfigureAwait(false)` that exist to resolve this type of problem don't work with `HttpClient`...

To doge this, you need to force the http call on a other thread. To do this, you can encapsulate the http call in a task like :

```cs
private async Task DownloadFile()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Download");
    HttpClient client = new();
    var response =  await Task.Run(() =>await client.GetAsync("file"));
    Debug.WriteLine("End download");
}
```

From .NET 5, `HttpClient` has (finaly) synchronous method :

```cs
private void DownloadFile()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Download");
    HttpClient client = new();
    var response = client.Get("file");
    Debug.WriteLine("End download");
}
```

But it's a bad practice to do heavy work in a constructor or on the main thread for UI program. Maybe you can consider to use `Form.Load` event.

Answer (score 0):

don't use async / await in combination with Wait() or Result, because it will result in a deadlock.

To avoid a deadlock within a SynchronizationContext, you should use ConfigureAwait(false):

```
private async Task DownloadFile()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Download");// appears
    HttpClient client = new();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("file").ConfigureAwait(false);
    Debug.WriteLine("End download");// does not display
}
```