# Thread.Sleep not working in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-express

I just found out about Thread.Sleep() and read a lot about it here:
[How to add a delay for a 2,3 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449956/how-to-add-a-delay-for-a-2-3-seconds)

The method doesn't get recognized when I try it in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 to close a very simple C# battle simulator (I put it at the bottom outside a While loop).

Comment: Note that using Thread.Sleep is *almost always the wrong thing to do*. Use Task.Delay to asynchronously wait, or create a timer and handle the timer event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( 2000 );
```

Comment: That worked perfect!  Should Thread.Sleep() alone suffice though?  Since most recommendations seem to include only that.

Comment: Just discovered you have to have using System.Threading; at the top.  Thanks again.

Comment: @RayLee: By using the using statement then you don't need the part defined in that statement.  So you can remove the System.Threading part.  Glad I could help, feel free to accept my answer (the tick under the score in top left of my answer).