# How can I make a delay inside my “for loop”?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, delay

How can I write a code to make a delay at the end of my “for loop” to make e.g. 1 millisecond delay before going through the next loop?

Comment: I don't think you can add a delay of 1 ms accurately , you may see this similar question for adding delay http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449956/how-to-add-a-delay-for-a-2-3-seconds?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: For such a small time delay (1ms) I'd probably use a spinner in conjunction with a `Stopwatch`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep(1)` will wait for *at least* 1 millisecond. More realistically it will sleep for about 16ms, as it gives up your thread's time slice and something else will get to run for a full time slice before it can resume.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Thread.Sleep(1)`

The input parameter for Thread.Sleep is the millisecond delay you want.

[Link to Sleep Method Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: but when i use thread its giving me error...

Comment: do i need to add any reference to my library?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: yes add a reference to `System.Threading`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Try{
Thread.Sleep(1);
}Catch(Exception e){
}
```

Comment: Why the try catch call? Can a Thread.Sleep() call cause an exception on its own?

Comment: yeah , IllegalSTate or INterrupted Exceptions

Comment: i can't use thread as it will terminate the whole programme. but i just need to put delay in part of my programme. how can i make a delay function plz?

Comment: why ? i mean why it will terminate the whole code? if u'll handle it in catch clause it will work smoothely..

Comment: another way, u can also use a free for loop till 1000 steps before executing your second loop

Comment: it will give little delay in computation...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to avoid the Thread class, and are using .NET 4.5 asynchronously, you can use the following:

```
await Task.Delay(1);
```