# How to make a delay with C# in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started to learn c# in unity. I followed a tutorial, but i wanna add some things.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public Text countText;
    public Text winText;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private int count;

    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        count = 0;
        SetCountText ();
        winText.text = "";
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ( "Pick Up"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
            count = count + 1;
            SetCountText ();
        }
    }

    void SetCountText ()
    {
        countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString ();
        if (count >= 1)
        {
            winText.text = "You Win!";
            Application.LoadLevel(1);
        }
    }

}
```

I wanna make a delay between winText.text = "You Win!"; 
and Application.LoadLevel(1); So you can actually read the text. I hope somebody can help me out!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5449956/3273247

Comment: That should help you 

Comment: That gives me a error: Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs(48,25): error CS0103: The name `Thread' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Try System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);

Comment: @FaceMann : that's because you would need to include the right namespace for it to compile. But calling `Thread.Sleep` is an awful code smell. And in your case it would block the UI thread, something you definitely don't want.

Comment: When i put System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); between winText.text and application.LoadLevel it pauzes for a second but the text you win isn't visible

Comment: @FaceMann : never use `Thread.Sleep`. Ever. Wipe this method from your memory and you'll become a better programmer.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is sometimes usefull with testing the appliaction behaviour

Comment: @JerrySwitalski Indeed, it is often useful for testing purpose, mostly to simulate a heavy load on a thread that makes it completely irresponsive (not something you should aim for). But it makes it to production quite often and is nearly always the symptom of something very wrong in the app.

Comment: How silly. You can't use Thread,Sleep in Unity, or any frame-based system. **Of course, JUST USE INVOKE is what the OP is looking for.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Coroutine (as I see this is Unity3D code):

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ( "Pick Up"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
            count = count + 1;
            StartCoroutine(SetCountText ());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SetCountText ()
    {
        countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString ();
        if (count >= 1)
        {
            winText.text = "You Win!";
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            Application.LoadLevel(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Specify in your answer that this way of doing is completely specific to Unity3D (and totally the right thing to do!)

Comment: True, I edited the question, as in my opinion the naming was wrong.

Comment: This answer is not good: An absolute beginner needs to learn about simple commands like `Invoke` first

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that it's a windows-forms application so that you're better not to use Thread.Sleep as it will block the UI thread.

Instead, use:
[System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://System.Windows.Forms.Timer)

Comment: This is a Unity application, so the windows form timer is not really an option, but you're right that `Thread.Sleep` is a very bad idea indeed.

Answer (score -1):

In Unity waits are usually done with help of a [WaitForSeconds](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) class.

In your case you will have to change `OnTriggerEnter` and `SetCountText` a bit so that they return `IEnumerable` type:

```
IEnumerable OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ( "Pick Up"))
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        count = count + 1;
        yield return SetCountText ();
    }
}

IEnumerable SetCountText ()
{
    countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString ();
    if (count >= 1)
    {
        winText.text = "You Win!";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5); // Wait for seconds before changing level
        Application.LoadLevel(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a beginner, the OP should just use `Invoke`.  This is a billion-times duplicate - nobody should have answered it.  This site is turning in to trash because people keep answering the lowest-quality Unity questions.