# If Statement Condition Time Check

Tags: c#, timer, kinect

I am trying to add a function to a program I am editing. In this program, I have various If statements that use a Microsoft Kinect device to check wherever a person is in a certain position or to check what their head movement is like etc, and depending what they are doing, display a type of feedback.

```
if (pitch > 10)
{ 
    //display icon
}
else if (pitch <10)
{ 
    //display icon
}
//etc..
```

At the moment, the icon is turning on/off rapidly depending on the users movement. As this may be confusing for users, I want the condition to match for some seconds before displaying it. e.g. if (pitch > 10) for X seconds then the display icon.

Not sure what the most efficient way of doing this, I have tried a timer and task delay but I think this just delays the results rather than check the condition over a time period.

Comment: [Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194845(v=vs.110).aspx) also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449956/how-to-add-a-delay-for-a-2-or-3-seconds

Comment: You have discovered histeresis! This is a well known problem for systems that interact directly with humans.

Comment: Assuming the above is in some sort of game loop, just store the time when the pitch first went > 10, clear it when pitch goes < 10, and check in each iteration of the loop whether `DateTime.Now` is > X seconds after the initial time.

Comment: I had a look at this already but I don't want the task to be delayed, I want the condition to be checked for an X amount of seconds before displaying the icon.

Comment: The first time your condition is true you can spin a timer via `Task.Delay()` for example to schedule the action you want to take followed by a `CancellationToken` something like: `Task.Delay(desireTime, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(ant => //your action)` Then if at anytime before your desiredTime the condition changed, you can use the token to cancel the execution.

Comment: I don't know if this was a typo in your code, but `if else` should be `else if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply count successful checks until needed number is reached

```
if (pitch > 10)
{ 
    if(counter++ > X)
    {
        //display icon
    }
}
else
    counter = 0; // reset
```

This is assuming it is possible to estimate number from time. Otherwise you would have to count time (resetting it if you get false condition)

You may implement *noise reduction* on top of that using same principle to avoid single error to hide icon.

Comment: Thank you, I went with this in the end and it worked perfectly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reorganize your main flow, with some intermediate queue/`BlockingCollection`+`GetConsumingEnumerable` where consuming part makes a delay before start processing any item

so very high level pseudocode:

```
BlockingCollection<IResult> blockingQueue ..

// Producer Task
IResult Process(IInputRequest params)
{
   if (...)
}

// Consuming Task
foreach ( .. blockingQueue.GetConsumerable...)
{
}
```

to accomodate pause use [Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx)

Please let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 0):

I would use Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this (NuGet "Rx-WinForms" or "Rx-WPF" depending on your UI).

Here's an example of changing the background of a form when hovering over a label for 3 seconds, but reverting it if the mouse moves away.

```
        var hovers =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern(h => label1.MouseEnter += h, h => label1.MouseEnter -= h)
                .Select(x => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0)))
                .Switch()
                .Select(x => System.Drawing.Color.Red);

        var leaves =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern(h => label1.MouseLeave += h, h => label1.MouseLeave -= h)
                .Select(x => System.Drawing.Color.White);

        var query = hovers.Merge(leaves);

        var subscription = query.ObserveOn(this).Subscribe(c => this.BackColor = c);
```