# Make A Delay For A Few Seconds

Tags: c#, delay

I have been wondering how to make a delay. I have tried thread.sleep but it stops the project. I would want to do something like:

```
Form4 ss = new Form4();
ss.Show();
wait(4000) //4000 miliseconds
ss.close();
```

I tried `await Task.Delay(4000);` but it said:
 I had the wrong return type
Please help

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(4000);`

Comment: I assume you are using WinForms. Thread.Sleep will stop your UI thread. Use `await Task.Delay(4000);` instead.

Comment: Is it winforms or what? Let me assume yes! Thread.Sleep(4000) blocks the messages on current thread so your window have no time to show itself. Instead do this: Task.Delay(4000)
                .ContinueWith(t=>form.Close(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

Comment: You seriously could not find any snippet anywhere showing how to do a delay??  The first google hit for your title: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5449956/1070452

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Task.Delay()`:

```
Form4 ss = new Form4();
ss.Show();
await Task.Delay(4000);
ss.Close();
```

Comment: When I try await Task.Delay(4000) it gives me this problem:

    The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: the error tells you what the problem means @AAAA come on man.. decorate your method with `async` start using Google please

Comment: Sorry lol, I did that and it gave me this error:
https://gyazo.com/b182a01a27ce0980bf1c769e97bf4013

Answer (score 1):

decorate your method like this

```
public async Task MyWaitMethod() 
{
    await Task.Run(async () => //Task.Run automatically unwraps nested Task types!
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    });
    Console.WriteLine("All done");
}
```

if you do not understand the first example use a simple straight forward one like this

```
public async Task MyWaitMethod() 
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: thanks but its saying it has the wrong return type. Heres a pic:
https://gyazo.com/b182a01a27ce0980bf1c769e97bf4013

Comment: @AA if the return type is important you should have included it in your question. And [don't post pictures of errors](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Comment: It is in the question

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer?

Create a timer with 4000 interval and set its tick event to close the form. replace your `wait(4000)` with Timer start event. Make sure to also stop the timer after closing your form.

Comment: this is so unnecessary when you can use the `Thread.Sleep()`

Comment: So would I do:
timer.interval = 1000
timer.Start();
timer.Stop();
MessageBox.Show("That was a 1 second delay")

Comment: @MethodMan The OP said that they tried `Tread.Sleep` but it "stops the project" (presumably winforms).

Comment: @AAAA it will take the same amount of time to try it as it does to comment, and then you will know and have a better question...

Comment: yeah still don't need to create a Timer

Comment: @AAAA do a google search on how to use `await Task.Delay()` method