# How to delay a certain task in c# .NET core 3.1

Tags: c#, delay, asp.net-core-3.1

NOTE: I am a noob at coding.

I am trying to make a certain task in my application run after a certain amount of time one (for example) I want `Console.WriteLine("Hello delay");` to run 180 seconds after `Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");` is run, how would I do that?

I have not tried anything else yet.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            // I want (Console.WriteLine("Hello delay");) to run 
            // 180 seconds after (Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");) is run
            Console.WriteLine("Hello delay");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a delay for a 2 or 3 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449956/how-to-add-a-delay-for-a-2-or-3-seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can sleep current thread.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Thread.Sleep(180 * 1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello delay");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir, this solved my problem!

Comment: Note that this is only acceptable in a single-threaded console application. Never sleep thread pool threads.

Answer (score 2):

Use Task.Run() to run a task and wait for its  completion.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

    var numSecondsDelay = 180;

    var t = Task.Run(async delegate
    {
        await Task.Delay(numSecondsDelay*1000);
        return numSecondsDelay;
    });
    t.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine("Hello delay");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
static async void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    
    await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello delay");
        });
        
    Console.WriteLine("Hello delay");
}
```

Comment: `Task.Run` runs the function on the thread pool and you should _never_ sleep on a thread pool thread.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Threading; // add this
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Thread.Sleep(180000); // add this
            Console.WriteLine("Hello delay");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to delay processing for 180 seconds.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(180 * 1000);
```